# How to convert SQL query to LINQ using RIA services?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, linq, ria

I'm starting with a SQL query that selects against a view & looks like this:

```
SET @id = ...
SET @variableDate = ...
SELECT Id,
        dbo.fnGreaterDateTime(ViewDate,@variableDate) AS GreaterDate,
    FROM vwExample
    WHERE Id = @id
```

The SQL function `fnGreaterDateTime` works as you would expect, returning the greater of the two values passed in.

I'm having trouble converting this to a LINQ query when using EF & RIA services.  In my Domain Service, I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
public IQueryable<ExampleViewResult> GetExampleViewResults(int id, DateTime variableDate)
{

    var query = from r in this.ObjectContext.ExampleViewResults
        where r.Id == id
        select new ExampleViewResult
          { 
            Id = r.Id,
            ViewDate = (r.ViewDate > variableDate) ? r.ViewDate : variableDate
          }
    return query;
}
```

But when I call this method I receive an error that says "The entity or complex type ExampleViewResult cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query".

I tried following some advice over in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query) thread, but when I have the domain service method return a list of DTOs instead, the auto-code generation doesn't include the method for use in my domain context.

Any ideas?

Comment: what happens if you do var listResults = this.OjbectContext.ExampleViewResults.ToList(); then var query = from r in listResults...

Comment: This can't be the actual code you have, as this will not compile (missing ;).  This makes me think you removed parts that you thought were not relevant, and those that could be the source of the problem.  Please post the complete code.

Comment: @cadrell0 - I did remove some parts that were just noise in the example.  Which problem are you referring to?   I'm looking for an alternate means of writing the query.

Comment: @Chris What I am trying to say is because LINQ uses deferred execution, perhaps that noise is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

see this question

[The entity cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query)

you just need to project to an anonymous type or a DTO