# Linq to Entities count subquery?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to do this query in linq to entities (EF4)

```sql
select Header.Id, 
 (select count(*) 
  from Detail 
  where Header.Id = Detail.headerId) detailcount
from Header
```

This won't work because it's not allowed in EF:
(Header and Detail are EntityObjects)

```cs
from h in context.Header
select new Header
    {
        Id = h.Id,
        DetailCount = (from d in context.Detail 
                       where d.headerId = p.Id select d).Count()
    }
```

DetailCount is a new property I added on the Detail Entity (partial class)

The above Linq query doesn't work because I cannot project onto a mapped entity: 
[The entity cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query)

Is there an other way of doing this?

Comment: is hearder and deatil has any relation like one to many ?

Comment: yes, one to many (one header, multiple details)

Comment: @Roeland Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by using annonymous types.

Answer (score 3):

below will do you task because both are related entities

```
from h in context.Header
select new Header
    {
        Id = h.Id,
        detailCount = h.Detail.Count()
    }
```

Comment: This is indeed a shorter version of the linq query, but the problem is that I cannot project onto a mapped entity.