# The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4.1

On our online billing application, we give a billing summary of what bills the customer received and the payments they made.

In order for this to work, I have to first pull the payments then match them to the bills. So I have do something like:

```
foreach (BillPaymentSummary payment in billPayments)
{
    DateTime dt = payment.DueDate;

    // Debug errors on this next line
    var summary = (from a in db.BillHistories
                   where a.CustomerId == customerNumber && a.DueDate == dt && a.Type == "BILL"
                   select new BillSummary
                   {
                       Id = a.Id,
                       CustomerId = a.CustomerId,
                       DueDate = a.DueDate,
                       PreviousBalance = a.PreviousBalance.Value,
                       TotalBill = a.TotalBill.Value,
                       Type = a.Type,
                       IsFinalBill = a.IsFinalBill
                   }).SingleOrDefault();

    if (summary != null)
    {
        summary.PayDate = payment.PaidDate;
        summary.AmountPaid = payment.AmountPaid;
        returnSummaries.Add(summary);
    }
    else
    {
        summary = (from a in db.BillHistories
                   where a.CustomerId == customerNumber && a.DueDate == payment.DueDate && a.Type == "ADJ "
                   select new BillSummary
                   {
                       Id = a.Id,
                       CustomerId = a.CustomerId,
                       DueDate = a.DueDate,
                       PreviousBalance = a.PreviousBalance.Value,
                       TotalBill = a.TotalBill.Value,
                       Type = a.Type,
                       IsFinalBill = a.IsFinalBill
                   }).SingleOrDefault();

        if (summary != null)
        {
            summary.PayDate = payment.PaidDate;
            summary.AmountPaid = payment.AmountPaid;
            returnSummaries.Add(summary);
        }
    }
}
```

I have been playing with this, but no matter what I do, I get the following error message:

> The entity or complex type 'UtilityBill.Domain.Concrete.BillSummary' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Is it because I am running queries within queries? How can I get around this error?

I have tried searching Google for an answer and see many answers, but none of them seem to explain my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The entity cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot project onto a mapped entity. You would have to call `ToList()` before doing your mapping.

Or better yet, change to the following (calling FirstOrDefault will execute the query and allow you to populate your object):

```
var summary = db.BillHistories.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CustomerId == customerNumber && a.DueDate == dt && a.Type == "BILL").Select(x => new BillSummary
                               {
                                   Id = a.Id,
                                   CustomerId = a.CustomerId,
                                   DueDate = a.DueDate,
                                   PreviousBalance = a.PreviousBalance.Value,
                                   TotalBill = a.TotalBill.Value,
                                   Type = a.Type,
                                   IsFinalBill = a.IsFinalBill
                               });
```

To decouple yourself from the Entity Framework you may want to also consider using a different model class to return instead of the Entity Framework model.

Comment: This got me on the right direction though not fully the right answer. I want to give you credit thought.

Comment: @MikeWills thanks for the rep! I think I did point out what was wrong with your code and how to fix it though.

Comment: @MikeWills i deleted my edit which indicated that calling `Where` and then `FirstOrDefault` would cause extra SQL to be generated as that does not appear to be the case. Maybe this was a problem in an earlier version because I have been following this rule for quite some time...or maybe it was just misinformation.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was:

```
        foreach (BillPaymentSummary payment in billPayments)
        {
            var data = db.BillHistories.Where(b => b.CustomerId == customerNumber && b.DueDate == payment.DueDate && b.Type == "B").FirstOrDefault();

            if (data != null) // There is a bill history
            {
                returnSummaries.Add(new BillSummary
                {
                    Id = data.Id,
                    CustomerId = data.CustomerId,
                    DueDate = data.DueDate,
                    PreviousBalance = data.PreviousBalance,
                    TotalBill = data.TotalBill,
                    Type = (data.Type.Trim() == "B" ? "BILL" : (data.Type == "A" ? "ADJ" : "")),
                    IsFinalBill = data.IsFinalBill,
                    PayDate = payment.PaidDate,
                    AmountPaid = payment.AmountPaid
                });
            }
            else // No bill history record, look for an adjustment
            {
                data = db.BillHistories.FirstOrDefault(b => b.CustomerId == customerNumber && b.DueDate == payment.DueDate && b.Type == "A");

                if (data != null)
                {
                    returnSummaries.Add(new BillSummary
                    {
                        Id = data.Id,
                        CustomerId = data.CustomerId,
                        DueDate = data.DueDate,
                        PreviousBalance = data.PreviousBalance,
                        TotalBill = data.TotalBill,
                        Type = (data.Type.Trim() == "B" ? "BILL" : (data.Type == "A" ? "ADJ" : "")),
                        IsFinalBill = data.IsFinalBill,
                        PayDate = payment.PaidDate,
                        AmountPaid = payment.AmountPaid
                    });
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: I think that is a terrible solution. Mapping anonymous types manually to defined entity classes. Not judging you though... I too feel like left in the rain by Microsoft... I you want to use an ORM, you want it to fill the gap between relational data and entity classes. This is not what is happening here.