# Getting only what is needed with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

With a plain connection to SQL Server, you can specify what columns to return in a simple `SELECT` statement.

With EF:

```
Dim who = context.Doctors.Find(3) ' Primary key is an integer
```

The above returns all data that entity has... BUT... I would only like to do what you can with SQL and get only what I need.

Doing this:

```
 Dim who= (From d In contect.Doctors
                     Where d.Regeneration = 3
                     Select New Doctor With {.Actor = d.Actor}).Single
```

Gives me this error:

> The entity or complex type XXXXX cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

So... How do I return only selected data from only one entity?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query) for a solution.

Comment: @JessevanAssen nice link, and good explanation for why in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is by setting the wanted properties in ViewModel "or DTO if you're dealing with upper levels"
Then as your example the ViewModel will be:

```
public class DoctorViewModel{
public string Actor {get;set;}
// You can add as many properties as you want
}
```

then the query will be:

```
var who = (From d In contect.Doctors
                     Where d.Regeneration = 3
                     Select New DoctorViewModel {Actor = d.Actor}).Single();
```

Sorry i wrote the code with C# but i think the idea is clear :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I'm not sure why, but Linq can't create the complex type. It would work if you were creating a anonymous type like (sorry c# code)

```
var who = (from x in contect.Doctors
           where x.Regeneration == 3
           select new { Actor = x.Actor }).Single();
```

you can then go

```
var doctor = new Doctor() {
    Actor = who.Actor
};
```

but it can't build it as a strongly typed or complex type like you're trying to do with

```
var who = (from x in contect.Doctors
           where x.Regeneration == 3
           select new Doctor { Actor = x.Actor }).Single();
```

also you may want to be careful with the use of `single`, if there is no doctor with the regeneration number or there are more than one it will throw a exception, `singleordefault` is safer but it will throw a exception if there is more than one match. `First` or `Firstordefault` are much better options `First` will throw a exception only if none exist and `Firstordefault` can handle pretty much anything

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply do this:

```
 Dim who= (From d In contect.Doctors
                     Where d.Regeneration = 3
                     Select d.Actor).Single
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim who = contect.Doctors.SingleOrDefault(Function(d) d.Regeneration = 3).Actor
```

Comment: Won't this throw an exception if there's no record with *Regeneration==3* ?