# The entity or complex type ' ' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The entity cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query)

```
   var tasks = from i in data.Incidents
                    join a in data.Accounts on i.CustomerID equals a.Acct_CID
                    select new Tasks()
                    {

                        creator_id = a.ID,
                        start_date = i.DateOpened,
                        end_date = i.DateCLosed,
                        product_code = i.ProductCode,
                        install_type = i.InstallType,
                        os = i.OSType,
                        details = i.Description,
                        solution = i.Solution,
                        creator_name = i.TechID,
                        category = i.Title,
                        text = "Ticket for" + " " + i.Name,
                        status_id = 7
                    };

        foreach (var task in tasks)
            data.Tasks.Add(task);
        data.SaveChanges();

 public class Incidents
    {
        [Key]
        public int IncidentID { get; set; }
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public string TechID { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOpened { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCLosed { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Solution { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string OSType{ get; set; }
        public string InstallType { get; set; }
        public string AddOnSoftware { get; set; }
        public string ScreenShare { get; set; }
    }
```

gives me an error when I try to iterate, I would love some help with this

Comment: It's not a duplicate as those questions did not answer mine

Comment: from the looks of it you are trying to project onto an Entity not a regular/anonymous type - so IMO they are the same. Bare in mind it says *possible* duplicate.

Comment: checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39880539/4251431

Answer (score 84, accepted):

In Linq-to-Entities you can only project to an anonymous type or a regular class. You can't project to an existing entity type. You can with linq-to-objects like so

```
var tasks = (from i in data.Incidents
            join a in data.Accounts on i.CustomerID equals a.Acct_CID
             select new
             {
               creator_id = a.ID,
               start_date = i.DateOpened,
               end_date = i.DateCLosed
              // ...
             }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Tasks {
               creator_id = x.creator_id,
               start_date = x.start_date,
               end_date = x.end_date              
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Error 9 Cannot initialize type 'TRX.CRM.Dashboard.Entities.DashBoard.Tasks' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: @Chazt3n - I added a `ToList` at the end. Give that a try

Comment: The `ToList` doesn't fix this. You can't use implied field names if it's not an anonymous type.

Comment: Thanks a million Aducci; I have been looking around for a few days now trying to get rid of a few other errors I was encountering and I finally got rid of them all.

Comment: You saved my day :)