# Error: The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with join query with MVC and i dont know why.

> The entity or complex type 'Tusofona_Website.Models.site_noticias' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

My Controller:

```
    private TusofonaDBs db = new TusofonaDBs();

    //
    // GET: /DestaquesMain/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var query = (from sd in db.site_desquesnoticias
                    join sn in db.site_noticias on sd.IDNoticia equals sn.IDNoticia
                    where sn.Destaque == 1
                    select new site_noticias {
                        CorpoNoticia = sn.CorpoNoticia,
                        TituloNoticia = sn.TituloNoticia
                    }).ToList();

        //return View(db.site_desquesnoticias.ToList());
          return View(query);

    }
```

My Model:

```
public class site_destaquesnoticias
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 IDDestaque { get; set; }
    public Int32 IDNoticia { get; set; }
    public string Foto { get; set; }


}

public class site_noticias
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 IDNoticia { get; set; }
    public string CorpoNoticia { get; set; }
    public string TituloNoticia { get; set; }
    public string Foto { get; set; }
    public Int32 Destaque { get; set; }
}

public class TusofonaDBs : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<site_destaquesnoticias> site_desquesnoticias { get; set; }
    public DbSet<site_noticias> site_noticias { get; set; }
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The entity cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't project onto a mapped entity (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916080/the-entity-or-complex-type-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query) answer).

However, you can do a couple of things:

1) Select an anonymous type instead of entity like:

```
var query = (from sd in db.site_desquesnoticias
                    join sn in db.site_noticias on sd.IDNoticia equals sn.IDNoticia
                    where sn.Destaque == 1
                    select new {
                        CorpoNoticia = sn.CorpoNoticia,
                        TituloNoticia = sn.TituloNoticia
                    }).ToList();
```

2) Invert your query to select the site_noticias directly. That depends on the query and the data that you would like to retrieve. For example, you can have a look if the following will work and give you the data that you need:

```
var query = (from sd in db.site_desquesnoticias
                    join sn in db.site_noticias on sd.IDNoticia equals sn.IDNoticia
                    where sn.Destaque == 1
                    select sn).ToList();
```

3) Use some DTO (Data transfer object) to project the properties that you want to select on to:

```
   public class SiteNoticiasDTO{
     public string CorpoNoticia {get;set;}
     public string TituloNoticia {get;set;}
    }

var query = (from sd in db.site_desquesnoticias
                    join sn in db.site_noticias on sd.IDNoticia equals sn.IDNoticia
                    where sn.Destaque == 1
                    select new SiteNoticiasDTO {
                        CorpoNoticia = sn.CorpoNoticia,
                        TituloNoticia = sn.TituloNoticia
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: The 2) answer work just fine. Probably this is a noob error, im still new with MVC :). Thank you so much.

Comment: This works, but the result becomes uneditable. How do you keep the result editable? Like foreach(item in query){ item.name = "append_something"; }. Editing the items doesn't return any errors, but it doesn't work.

Comment: 3 didn't work for me as casting ProductDTO to needed Product entity returns error:

    Unable to cast the type 'xyz.Controllers.ProductDTO' to type 'xyz.Models.Product'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types. I need to return IQueriable<Product> to paging method: is there a way to cast back from DTO to required entity?

Comment: 1. did not work for me. same as above: casting to required return type I get: 'Unable to cast the type Anonymous type' to type 'xyz.Models.Product'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types