# how to pass custom query results to view in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i wants to pass the data from my controller to view.
here is code of controller

```
public ActionResult AllCars()
    {
        try
        {
            int id = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();


            var reservedCars = (from c in db.Cars

                            join o in db.Orders on c.Car_Id equals o.Car_Id
                            join u in db.AspNetUsers on o.Id equals u.Id
                            where u.Id == 5
                            select new
                            {
                                c.Car_Description,
                                c.Car_Id,
                                c.CarMakeId,
                                c.CarModelId,
                                c.Reservation_Status,
                                c.Color
                            });

        return View(reservedCars);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

here is my view file.

```
@model IEnumerable<FinalProject.Models.ReservedCar>



<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Car_Id);
            </td>
        </tr>
     }
    </table>
```

**but when i run my view i got following error 
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable`**

i know im passing dbquery result to view and my view is expecting it will be iEnumerable.
Please guide me how i can achieve thhis task.? i just wants to pass query results into my view and wants to use it.

ModelClass.
ReservedCar.cs

```
namespace FinalProject.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    public partial class ReservedCar
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Car_Description { get; set; }

        public int Car_Id { get; set; }

        public string CarMakeId { get; set; }

        public string CarModelId { get; set; }
        public string Reservation_Status { get; set; }

        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: end your query with `.ToList()` or pass to the view `reservedCars.ToList()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently `reservedCars` is still a query expression of type `IQueryable`. It hasn't been evaluated/executed yet. So the type of `reservedCars` is different than the type your view is strongly typed to(`IEnumerable<ReservedCar>`). That is the reason you are getting the type mismatch error.

Make sure you are returning a collection of `ReservedCar` class. You can update the projection part of your LINQ expression to project the result to `ReservedCar` instead of an anonymous object. Also call `ToList()` method on the query which will execute the query expression and return the results of that.

```
 var reservedCars = (from c in db.Cars

                            join o in db.Orders on c.Car_Id equals o.Car_Id
                            join u in db.AspNetUsers on o.Id equals u.Id
                            where u.Id == 5
                            select new ReservedCarVm
                            {
                                CarId = c.Car_Id,
                                Description = c.Car_Description,
                                Color = c.Color
                                // Map other properties as needed.
                            }).ToList();
return View(reserverCars);
```

Assuming your `ReservedCarVm` class has  `Color`,`Car_Description` and `Car_Id` properties which is of same type of those in the `Car` entity class like below

```
public class ReservedCarVm
{
  public string Color { set;get;}
  public string Description { set;get;}
 //Add other properties needed by the view here
}
```

Now make sure your view is strongly typed to the collection of this view model class

```
@model IEnumerable<ReserverdCarVm>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <p>@item.CarId</p>
  <p>@item.Color</p>
}
```

Comment: still getting error in controller.
'FinalProject.Models.ReservedCar' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
Answer is updated. Please check my Model class.

Comment: Do you have a class called ReserverCar ? How does it looks like ? Does it have the same proeprties as we used ?

Comment: check my model class in updated question.  yeah it have all these properties.

Comment: How does the `Car` class looks like ? Do they have the same properties ?

Comment: yes i checked closely and i have all these properties in Car model. but still getting following error.
Additional information: The entity or complex type 'FinalProject.Models.ReservedCar' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: its not working. i check each and every thing. 
Additional information: The entity or complex type 'FinalProject.Models.ReservedCar' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
:-(

Comment: finaly i resolved my problem. we cant use model object in linq query.
Read this issue. to resolve this problem that i was facing.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916080/the-entity-or-complex-type-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121434/discussion-between-shyju-and-muhammad-ateek).

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

Instead of  @model IEnumerable< FinalProject.Models.ReservedCar>
you could do @model IQueryable< FinalProject.Models.ReservedCar>

The above is not recommended, you should not  call database directly from the view, I don't see any reason for doing that.

Also you need to dispose the dbcontext, in the code you provided, you are not disposing the dbconext which is not good

just redo your code by this

```
var reservedCars = (from c in db.Cars

                            join o in db.Orders on c.Car_Id equals o.Car_Id
                            join u in db.AspNetUsers on o.Id equals u.Id
                            where u.Id == 5
                            select new
                            {
                                c.Car_Description,
                                c.Car_Id,
                                c.CarMakeId,
                                c.CarModelId,
                                c.Reservation_Status,
                                c.Color
                            }).ToList();
  db.Dispose();
```

Comment: still getting error by your way of code and solution.
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery` but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`

Comment: why do you need query in  view ?