# The entity or complex type ' ' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, linq

I keep getting an error and I can't figure out the source of it. I'm trying to do a simple image upload connected to an item and when trying to pull the list I get the following error:

> The entity or complex type ' ' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var content = db.Items.Select(s => new
    {
        s.Id,
        s.Image,
        s.Price,
        s.Quantity,
    });

    List<Item> contentModel = content.Select(item => new Item()
    {
        Id = item.Id,
        Image = item.Image,
        Price = item.Price,
        Quantity = item.Quantity,
    }).ToList();

    return View(contentModel);
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `Image`?

Comment: Image is a byte[]

Comment: Why is your code performing a `Select` to a new anonymous type and then taking it directly to `new Item`? Why not go directly: `db.Items.Select( s => new Item() { ... })`?

Comment: Sorry could you explain a bit more this is my first attempt at this

Comment: In LINQ to Entities you cannot project to an existing entity type but only to an anonymous type or a regular class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The entity or complex type ' ' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916080/the-entity-or-complex-type-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query)

Comment: What is the point of this? Why not just use `var content = db.Items.ToList()`?

Answer (score 0):

If your data-source is a SQL database you have to call `ToList` before you call `Select` with a Expression that is non translatable into SQL.

```
content.ToList().Select(...)
```

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I double-checked this and if i omit the `ToList` I got the same exception.