# entity framework 5 take and order by in include

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I want to retrieve an object plus its filtered/ordered collection property using EF 5. However, my current code throws an exception:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties

Here is the class of the object I want to retrieve:

```
public class EntryCollection
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Entry> Entries { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And here is the definition of `Entry`:

```
public class Entry
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Added { get; set; }

    ... 
}
```

I wanted to retrieve the `EntryCollection` which contains only the most recent entries, so here is the code I tried:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    return db.EntryCollections
             .Include(ec => ec.Entries.OrderByDescending(e => e.Added).Take(5))
             .SingleOrDefault(ec => ec.Foo == "bar');
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use OrderBy inside an include.

what about the following

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    return db.EntryCollections
             .Where(ec => ec.Foo == "bar")
             .Select(ec=> new Something{Entries = ec.Entries.OrderByDescending(e => e.Added).Take(5) }, /*some other properties*/)
             .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

or do it in two seperate queries

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Can 'Something' be EntryCollection? When I tried that I got an exception: 'The entity or complex type 'MyNamespace.EntryCollection' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.'.

Comment: Looks like the answer to my previous comment can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query?rq=1 I might have to go with two queries on this one.

Comment: I went with two separate queries. First to load the EntryCollection without the entries. Then another one to load the entries.