# In constructors and initializers, only property or field parameter bindings are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I am able to execute the below code snippet in my application with no problem.

```
Projects.Select(s =>
                        new ProjectName()
                        {
                            ProjectID = s.ProjectID,
                            Name = s.Name
                        })
```

Note that ProjectName is a parameterless constructor which exists in the following class:

```
    namespace YeagerTechModel.DropDownLists
    {
       [DataContract]
        [Serializable]
        public partial class ProjectName
        {
            [DataMember]
            public Int16 ProjectID { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public String Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

However, I am **not** able to run the following query in my application. There are no design time compile errors. I only get the error in the subject of this post at run time in a "Catch" statement.

```
Projects.Where(w => w.Status.Description == "Not Started").Select(s =>
                        new CustomerProjectDDL()
                        {
                             ProjectName =
                            {
                               ProjectID = s.Project,
                               Name = s.Name
                            },

                             Customer =
                            {
                                CustomerID = s.CustomerID,
                                Email = s.Customer.Email,
                                City = s.Customer.City,
                                State = s.Customer.State,
                                Zip = s.Customer.Zip
                            }

                        })
```

Note that CustomerProjectDDL is a parameterless constructor which contains two classes.

```
namespace YeagerTechModel.ViewModels
{
    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public partial class CustomerProjectDDL
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Customer Customer = new Customer();
        [DataMember]
        public ProjectName ProjectName = new ProjectName();
    }
}
```

I need both of these classes in my View since it needs properties from both. The Customer object was generated from a Code generation item on the ORM in Visual Studio using DbContext which has all its properties and the ProjectName class is the first class I specified above in the post.

I would appreciate any help...

Besides using **AutoMapper** and **manually typing in the properties into your new ViewModel**, **how do you get data from two or more separate tables in one model to satisfy the View?**

I thought what I did was a good concept. Take any of the generated DbContext or any other classes and simply place them inside a superclass (like the CustomerProjectDDL class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `new` keyword when you `.Select` on the object:

```
Projects.Where(w => w.Status.Description == "Not Started").Select(s =>
                        new CustomerProjectDDL()
                        {
                            ProjectName = new ProjectName()
                            {
                                ProjectID = s.Project,
                                Name = s.Name
                            },

                            Customer = new Customer()
                            {
                                CustomerID = s.CustomerID,
                                Email = s.Customer.Email,
                                City = s.Customer.City,
                                State = s.Customer.State,
                                Zip = s.Customer.Zip
                            }    
                        });
```

### sagesky36

My Customer object looks like this:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace YeagerTechModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    [Serializable,  DataContract(IsReference = true)] 
     public partial class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            this.Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
        }

        [DataMember] public short CustomerID { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string UserName { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string Email { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string Company { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string Address1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string Address2 { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string City { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string State { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string Zip { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string HomePhone { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string CellPhone { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string Website { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string IMAddress { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember] public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Easy to make stupid mistakes when you rush trying to answer, @Habib ;)

Comment: Almost there.... I am now getting the following error: "{"The entity or complex type 'YeagerTechModel.Customer' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."}" I will edit my post and let you see what is inside the Customer class. Please let me know how I can modify it to satisfy the linq query.

Comment: @sagesky36 look at this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query

Comment: I see.... Instead of actually using the mapped entity class, I created another class in my ViewModel folder and copied the code from the generated class into the ViewModel class. I'll update my code to show you what I did. Thanks so much for your help.