# How to select 2 columns with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there a way to run a query using a textbox value & get two columns in return using Entity Framework and insert the values to another table?

tried with single column with no luck.

```
string warehouse = new DBEntities()
    .emps
    .Where(u => u.emp_id == txt_employee_pack.Text)
    .Select(u => u.sic)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  What didn't work as expected?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Tried with a single column with no luck of getting a result. see update post

Comment: Duplicate of: [Select Multiple Fields from List in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202981/select-multiple-fields-from-list-in-linq), [Select multiple columns using Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19536064/8967612)