# Cast Error in Linq Query

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to get data for a gridview and have a cast error.

In the code below, if I just return "myuserlist" - all is good.  As soon as I try to select only 2 fields (as in this code), I get the casting error.  I've looked at other comments posted here regarding this problem and tried a number of things with no success.

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports RoutesEntities

Partial Class ProfileTest
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private myentity As New RoutesEntities()

    Public Function GridView1_GetData() As IQueryable(Of AllUser)
        Return From myuserlist In myentity.AllUsers Select New With {myuserlist.UserName,myuserlist.Email}
    End Function
```

Error:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2147467262
Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_0`2[System.String,System.String]]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[AllUser]'.
Source=App_Web_oelfrca5
StackTrace:
   at ProfileTest.GridView1_GetData() in C:\xxx\yyy\zzz\Profile.aspx.vb:line 10
InnerException:
```

I tried this (among other things):

```
Return From myuserlist In myentity.AllUsers Select New AllUser() With {
               .UserName = myuserlist.UserName,
               .Email = myuserlist.Email}
```

and got this:

```
Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The entity or complex type 'RoutesModel.AllUser' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
```

Comment: Although it is a post (and a good answer) for C#, this applies also for VB.NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the specific `AllUser` type at compile-time, you can have your function return an `IQueryable(Of Object)`, or perhaps even a simple `IQueryable`:

```
Public Function GridView1_GetData() As IQueryable
    Return From myuserlist In myentity.AllUsers Select New With {myuserlist.UserName,myuserlist.Email}
End Function
```

**Update** Return `IQueryable(Of Object)` if you'll need LINQ on the results:

```
Sub DataTest()
    Dim qry = GridView1_GetData
    Dim filteredQry = qry.Take(5)
End Sub
```

<del>It is easier to do this with VB.NET than in C#, because VB.NET supports late binding -- even though the variable `x` is of type `Object`, and thus may not have a `UserName` property, the compiler will allow `UserName` to be resolved at runtime.</del>

This is not as useful as it might be, because you can't pass an expression into the LINQ operator, e.g. you can use `.Take` or one overload of `.Any`, but not `.Where`.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I tried for a couple of hours with all the other C# suggestions (trying to convert to VB) with utter failure.  Your code worked out-of-the-box.  However, could you shed a little light on why wouldn't I just use IQuerable all the time and never use IQueryable(Of xxxx).  Your method works also for returning the entire "myuserlist" with no sub-list.  Am I giving up something?  And thanks again!

Comment: @user2923427 Updated. What do you mean by a sub-list?

Comment: Sorry for poor terminology - I just meant this works also: Return From myuserlist In myentity.AllUsers Select myuserlist

Comment: @user2923427 When using `Select` you are defining a **projection** -- each element should be projected into a new element. (The new element can be a different type -- in the first example, each `AllUser` is being projected to an anonymously typed object (with `UserName` and `Email` string properties)). However, there is no point in projecting each element to itself; you can just write `Return myentity.AllUsers.AsQueryable`.

Comment: Thanks Zev.  If I can pursue a bit more the line: "Dim filteredQry = qry.Where(Function(x) x.UserName.StartsWith("a")).Take(5)"  I can't get this work even reduced to: Dim filteredQry = qry.Where(Function(x) x.UserName) - I keep getting this error in the editor "late binding objects can't be converted to an expression tree"  I can see where this general idea is useful but I just can't get it to get beyond this syntax error.

Comment: @user2923427 My mistake -- even though in general you can use variables of Object this way, you can't do it within an expression, which is what many of the LINQ methods on `IQueryable` expect.