# Another cannot implicity convert type IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I'm sorry for posting another convert type error, but after looking through and trying every example for nearly two days now, I can't get this to work.

What do I need to do to get this to work????

```
    public IEnumerable<Product> BindProductDropDown([Control("ddBrand")] int BrandID)
    {
        if (BrandID > 0)
        {
            try
            {


                var prod = (from p in _DbContext.Products
                            join pc in _DbContext.ProductCategories on p.ProductCategoryID equals pc.ProductCategoryId
                            where pc.BrandID == BrandID
                            orderby p.OrderBy, p.Name
                            select new 
                            {
                                p.ProductID,
                                p.ItemNumber
                            });
                var c = prod.Count();
                return prod;

            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                ErrorLabel.Text = exp.Message;
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorLabel.Text = "Please select a brand from the drop drown list of brands above.";
            return null;
        }
    }
```

#

```
  public IEnumerable<Product> BindProductDropDown([Control("ddBrand")] int BrandID)
    {
        if (BrandID > 0)
        {
            try
            {


                var prod = (from p in _DbContext.Products
                            join pc in _DbContext.ProductCategories on p.ProductCategoryID equals pc.ProductCategoryId
                            where pc.BrandID == BrandID
                            orderby p.OrderBy, p.Name
                            select new Product
                            {
                                p.ProductID,
                                p.ItemNumber
                            });
                var c = prod.Count();
                return prod;

            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                ErrorLabel.Text = exp.Message;
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorLabel.Text = "Please select a brand from the drop drown list of brands above.";
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query) may be helpful for the second error you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prod` is a `IEnumerable<AnonymousType>` you need to create `Product` in order to compile.

```
select new Product
    {
       ProductID = p.ProductID,
       ItemNumber = p.ItemNumber
    });
```

If you're not aware of "Anonymous Types" you can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) and [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/06/21/c.net-little-wonders-the-joy-of-anonymous-types.aspx)

Comment: I tried that but get the error 'Cannot initialize type (model product) with a collection initializer because it does not implement System... IEnumerable

Comment: Am sure you're doing it wrong, post the updated code so that we can see what is wrong.

Comment: @SheriTrager Check my answer carefully. You need to use `ProductID = p.ProductID,` not just `p.ProductID`. and so on.

Comment: You are great!  Thank you so much for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Just walked through the code and got the following error:-(
The entity or complex type 'Models.Product' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: @SheriTrager That's a different problem, I suggest you to ask new question with more info about the error (if runtime excecption post stacktrace etc).