# Cannot initialize type "MyDataCollection" with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx

Hi All i am facing above error.
I want retrieve only two columns from database using edmx.
While running i get following error:

> "cannot initialize type with a collection initializer because it does
>   not implement ienumerable."

```
using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
{
    IList<myData> objData = null;
    objData = context.EDatas
        .Where(entity => entity.Status == 0 && entity.Id == Id)
        .Select(entity => new myData
        { 
            entity.ID, 
            entity.Key                          
        }).ToList();                  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
.Select(entity => new myData
{ 
    entity.ID, 
    entity.Key                          
})
```

You need to use the correct property names of `myData`:

```
.Select(entity => new myData
{ 
    ID = entity.ID, 
    Key = entity.Key                          
})
```

otherwise the compiler assumes that you want to fill a collection.

Comment: I have tried this it gives below error "The entity or complex type 'DBModel.myData' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query"

Comment: @SantoshSingh: i'm not familiar with L2E, here is the reason and the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating an anonymous type, and compiler thinks that you are creating a collection using collection initializer syntax. You should use the property names and set values like this:

```
.Select(entity => new myData
                  { 
                       Id = entity.ID, 
                       Key = entity.Key                          
                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: I have tried this it gives below error "The entity or complex type 'DBModel.myData' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query"

Comment: @SantoshSingh add AsEnumerable after Where.