# How to select the properties to be filled instead of all properties of the object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I have a large table and I need to select some fields not all of them.

I would to do something like this:

```
select column 2, column3 from tableName order by column2
```

But I'm trying it and it's doing a error.

```
public List<RiskCard> GetAllAcitveRiskCardsBasicProperties(Company company)
{
    return GetDbSet<RiskCard>()
       .Where(i => i.Company.CompanyId == company.CompanyId && i.Active == true)
       .OrderBy(o => o.PremisesName)
       .Select(o => new RiskCard { RiskCardId = o.RiskCardId, PremisesName = o.PremisesName}).ToList();
}
```

The error is;

***The entity or complex type 'my.namespace.RiskCard' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.***

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the error message, don't construct an *entity* in your LINQ to Entities query, you can create an anonymous type instead. Then you can construct the entities in LINQ to object query later on :

```
var query = GetDbSet<RiskCard>()
           .Where(i => i.Company.CompanyId == company.CompanyId && i.Active == true)
           .OrderBy(o => o.PremisesName)
           .Select(o => new { RiskCardId = o.RiskCardId, PremisesName = o.PremisesName})
           .ToList();

return query.Select(o => new RiskCard { RiskCardId = o.RiskCardId, PremisesName = o.PremisesName})
            .ToList();
```

Related question : [The entity cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query)

Comment: Saw this article but what is the signature of a method of type anonymous?

I tried 
`public List<T> MethodName(){



}`

And the visual studio complain about the namespace of T.

Comment: I haven't tested this, so you don't want to return `RiskCard` as shown in this answer (you want to just return anonymous type instead) or this answer just didn't actually work for you? The signature can be `List<dynamic>`