# ASP.NET MVC LINQ Grouping

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to group multiple items according to one column from my database table. I have combed through countless posts covering this topic and have had no luck in solving my issue.

This is the tutorial that I am following that does exactly what I need: http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/grouping-data-with-linq-and-mvc/

This is what my Table Definition looks like:

```
|task_no(PK)|task_statement|field_name|
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to get:

```
field_name 1
  task_no | task_statement
  task_no | task_statement
  task_no | task_statement
field_name 2
  task_no | task_statement
  task_no | task_statement
field_name 3
  task_no | task_statement
  task_no | task_statement
```

Here are my models:

```
public partial class domain_names_tasks
{
    [Key]public int task_no { get; set; }
    public string task_statement { get; set; }
    public string field_name { get; set; }
}
```

class created from following tutorial.

```
    public class Group<T, K>
{
    public K Key;
    public IEnumerable<T> Values;
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
    public ActionResult DomainTaskStatements()
    {
        var taskStatements = context.domain_names_tasks.Select(ts => new domain_names_tasks
                                                            {
                                                                task_no = ts.task_no,
                                                                task_statement = ts.task_statement,
                                                                field_name = ts.field_name
                                                            }).ToList();

        var data = from ts in taskStatements
                   group ts by ts.field_name into tsg
                   select new Group<string, domain_names_tasks> { Key = tsg.Key, Values = tsg };
        return View(data.toList());
    }
```

I am getting two errors:

1st Error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'GeologyWebApp.Models.domain_names_tasks'
```

which is being caused here:

```
Key = tsg.Key
```

2nd Error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string,GeologyWebApp.Models.domain_names_tasks>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

being caused here:

```
Values = tsg
```

I am new to using LINQ and ASP.NET so I apologize for asking a question about an issue that may be simple to solve. I have had no luck looking though other questions related to LINQ grouping so I thought I would post this question. Thanks in advance!

Edit 1 -------

Sorry I did not notice my silly mistake with the Key and Value parameters in the Group class.

Here is my revised controller and view that now work.

Controller:

NOTE: I had to change my "taskStatements" query because I was getting the error: "The entity cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query". I followed an answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query) to fix this issue.

```
    public ActionResult DomainTaskStatements()
    {
        var taskStatements = (from ts in context.Set<domain_names_tasks>()
                  select new
                  {
                      task_no = ts.task_no,
                      task_statement = ts.task_statement,
                      field_name = ts.field_name
                  }).ToList().Select(x => new domain_names_tasks { task_no = x.task_no, task_statement = x.task_statement, field_name = x.field_name });

        var data = from ts in taskStatements
                   group ts by ts.field_name into tsg
                   select new Group<string, domain_names_tasks> { Key = tsg.Key, Values = tsg };
        return View(data.ToList());
    }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<GeologyWebApp.Models.Group<string, GeologyWebApp.Models.domain_names_tasks>>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DomainTaskStatements";
}

<table>
    <thead><tr><th>task no</th><th>task statement</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var group in Model)
        {
            <tr><th colspan="2">@group.Key</th></tr>
            foreach (var task in group.Values)
            {
                <tr><td>@task.task_no</td><td>@task.task_statement</td></tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select new Group<string, domain_names_tasks> { Key = tsg.Key, Values = tsg };
```

should probably be

```
select new Group<domain_names_tasks, string> { Key = tsg.Key, Values = tsg };
```

because on

```
Group<T, K>
```

the key (K) is the second type parameter and the type (T) is the first.

---

However, I don't believe you need to have your own Group type, using 'group by' in LINQ should return:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<K,T>>
```

You could probably get away with this in the controller:

```
var data = from ts in taskStatements
           group ts by ts.field_name;
```

and then this in the view (for the nested loop):

```
foreach (var task in group)
```

instead of

```
foreach (var task in group.Values)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! You are correct about the parameters for Group. I am sorry I made the silly mistake of overlooking that.. I am not sure about not using my own Group type. I tried what you suggested but am getting the following error in the nested for each loop: "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'GeologyWebApp.Models.domain_names_tasks' because 'GeologyWebApp.Models.domain_names_tasks' does not contain a public definition of 'GetEnumerator'". Any ideas on this?

Comment: Hmm, what were you using for the model directive? I think it should be something like 'IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,domain_names_tasks>>'? (only with the namespaces, System.Linq.IGrouping/GeologyWebApp.Models or using directives for them)