# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<PesquisaView.view_ok>'

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to do a simple method to return a list. But an error occurs: *Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IList<PesquisaView.view_ok>`.*

I tried a lot of things, but I could not find a example with parameters and LINQ to resolve this problem.

Any help?

CODE:

```
public class LinqQuery
{
    public IList<view_ok> GetPesquisar(string r8, string r9, string r10, string r11, string sexo, string prof)
    {

        string rs8 = r8;
        string rs9 = r9;
        string rs10 = r10;
        string rs11 = r11;
        string sex = sexo;
        string pr = prof;

        PesquisaBETAEntities pb = new PesquisaBETAEntities();

    var query =  
`   (from t0 in (
    (from v0 in pb.view_ok
    group v0 by new {
        v0.prof_nome,
        v0.resu1
    } into g
    select new {
        g.Key.prof_nome,
        g.Key.resu1}))
    join t1 in (
    from v1 in pb.view_ok
        where Convert.ToString(v1.resu8).Contains(rs8) && Convert.ToString(v1.resu9).Contains(rs9) 
        && Convert.ToString(v1.resu10).Contains(rs10) && Convert.ToString(v1.resu11).Contains(rs11)   && Convert.ToString(v1.sexo).Contains(sex)
    group v1 by new {
      v1.prof_nome,
      v1.resu1
    } into g
    select new {
      g.Key.prof_nome,
      g.Key.resu1,
      perguntas = g.Count(p => p.resu1 != null)
    })
      on new { t0.prof_nome, Resu1 = t0.resu1 }
     equals new { t1.prof_nome, Resu1 = t1.resu1 } into t1_join
    from t1 in t1_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
`
```

..............

repeat the Linq for 7 joins, and the end is:

.............

```
select new {
t0.prof_nome,
resultado = Convert.ToString(t0.resu1) == "60" ? "Regular" : Convert.ToString(t0.resu1) == "80" ?     "Bom" : 
Convert.ToString(t0.resu1) == "90" ? "Ótimo" : Convert.ToString(t0.resu1) == "100" ? "Excelente" : null,
p1 = (int?)t1.perguntas,
p2 = (int?)t2.perguntas,
p3 = (int?)t3.perguntas,
p4 = (int?)t4.perguntas,
p5 = (int?)t5.perguntas,
p6 = (int?)t6.perguntas,
p7 = (int?)t7.perguntas
}).ToList();

        return query;
```

But the error occurs in "return query"

Thanks

Comment: It's because you're selecting "new", try explicitly specify the type of list in the select new part.

Comment: Could you give a example (or link to I undestand)? I'm learning.

Comment: I admittedly have not tried to understand the code at all, but I would not do this all in one linq call. It's too unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List<view_ok> ListarPesquisa(string prof)
    {
        PesquisaBETAEntities pb = new PesquisaBETAEntities();

        var query = (from t0 in
                         (from v0 in pb.view_ok
                          group v0 by new
                          {
                              v0.prof_nome,
                              v0.resu1
                          }
                              into gg
                              select new
                              {
                                  gg.Key.prof_nome,
                                  gg.Key.resu1
                              })
                       where t0.prof_nome.Contains(prof)
                     select new view_ok{ Professor = t0.prof_nome, P1 = t0.resu1 }).ToList();

        return query;

    }
```

By default select new will select an enumerable of anonymous type.

Reference:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2008/01/25/using-your-own-defined-type-in-a-linq-query-expression.aspx

Comment: When I wrote the code, the error don't occurs. But when I run the project, the error in run time is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: The entity or complex type 'PesquisaBETAModel.view_ok' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: @Elber Is PesquisaBETAModel.view_ok a complex type? (Is it a view in the database?) or is it a class?

Comment: @Elber Oh...Sorry I thought it is a class, then you'll have to take a look at this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query. You can't map fields onto a mapped entity, you'll have to make a DTO and map the desired fields onto it..

Answer (score 0):

I made more simple, but the error occurs in the same way:

```
    public List<view_ok> ListarPesquisa(string prof)
    {
        PesquisaBETAEntities pb = new PesquisaBETAEntities();

        var query = (from t0 in
                         (from v0 in pb.view_ok
                          group v0 by new
                          {
                              v0.prof_nome,
                              v0.resu1
                          }
                              into gg
                              select new
                              {
                                  gg.Key.prof_nome,
                                  gg.Key.resu1
                              })
                       where t0.prof_nome.Contains(prof)
                     select new { Professor = t0.prof_nome, P1 = t0.resu1 }).ToList();

        return query;

    }
```

Comment: Please take a look at my solution, see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

The new code doesn't appears problem in code, but when I Run the project, the Entity F. don't work with the error:

'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll Additional information: The entity or complex type 'PesquisaBETAModel.view_ok' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

```
    public List<view_ok> ListarPesquisa(string prof)
    {
        PesquisaBETAEntities pb = new PesquisaBETAEntities();

        var query = (from t0 in pb.view_ok
                     where t0.prof_nome.Contains(prof)
                     select new view_ok { prof_nome = t0.prof_nome, resu1 = t0.resu1 }).ToList();
        return query;

    }
```