# Assign value to String Property based on integer Property value in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a `linq query`, and want to assign string value to a string property, which in dependent on another int property value. I have saved int value in database, and now want to get appropriate string value for the saved integer value. Below is my query..

```
 var data = db.ProjectSetups.Select(c => new ProjectSetup
                {
                    ProjectId = c.ProjectId,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    NameArabic = c.NameArabic,
                    StartDate = c.StartDate,
                    EndDate = c.EndDate,
                    Date = c.Date,
                    StringType = (c.Type.ToInt32() == 1 ? "Development" : "Rental").ToString(),
                    StringStatus = (c.Status == 1 ? "InProgress" :
                    c.Status == 2 ? "Completed" :
                    c.Status == 3 ? "Dividend" : "Closed"),
                    LandArea = c.LandArea,
                    SaleAmount = c.SaleAmount

                }).ToList();
```

**I got below error**

**The entity or complex type 'PMISModel.ProjectSetup' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query**

Comment: You cannot do that  onto a mapped entity.Check this,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var data = db.ProjectSetups.ToList();
     data = data.Select(c => new ProjectSetup
                        {
                            ProjectId = c.ProjectId,
                            Name = c.Name,
                            NameArabic = c.NameArabic,
                            StartDate = c.StartDate,
                            EndDate = c.EndDate,
                            Date = c.Date,
                            StringType = (c.Type.ToInt32() == 1 ? "Development" : "Rental").ToString(),
                            StringStatus = (c.Status == 1 ? "InProgress" :
                            c.Status == 2 ? "Completed" :
                            c.Status == 3 ? "Dividend" : "Closed"),
                            LandArea = c.LandArea,
                            SaleAmount = c.SaleAmount

                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: You probably should point out that you added `.ToList();` and why you did so.