# LINQ left join ordered with empty right-items at the end

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, join

My understanding of LINQ and Entity Framework is minimal, and I'm learning as I go along...

I am trying to write a query that takes the information from a **view** called `GroupView` and does a left-join on a table called `GroupSequence`... the information is then to be used by an `<asp:Repeater>`.

The resultant set should have **all** the items from `GroupView` with the joined items at the start (in sequence defined by the `GroupSequence` table) and with non-joined items at the end (in sequence defined by the `Id` of the `GroupView` items).

I.e...

```
[GroupView]             |    [GroupSequence]
[Id]  [Name]   [Calc]   |    [Id]  [GroupId]  [UserId]  [Sequence]
1     Group 1  23       |    1     1          1         3
2     Group 2  34       |    2     2          1         2
3     Group 3  45       |    3     3          1         1
4     Group 4  56
5     Group 5  67
```

With the expected outcome of...

```
[Id]  [Name]   [Calc]
3     Group 3  45
2     Group 2  34
1     Group 1  23
4     Group 4  56
5     Group 5  67
```

If I do the following, despite using the `DefaultIfEmpty`, all I get is the 3 groups linked to the sequence.  But the page displays, even though it's only 3 rows...

```
from @group in context.GroupViews
join seq in context.GroupSequences on @group.Id equals seq.GroupId into groupSeq
from item in groupSeq.DefaultIfEmpty()
where item.UserId == 1
orderby item.Sequence
select new { Id = @group.Id, Name = @group.Name, Calc = @group.Calc };
```

If I do the following, the `.DataBind` on the repeater complains that...

> The entity or complex type 'DevModel.GroupSequence' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

```
from @group in context.GroupViews
join seq in context.GroupSequences on @group.Id equals seq.GroupId into groupSeq
from item in groupSeq.DefaultIfEmpty(new GroupSequence { Id = @group.Id, UserId = 1, Sequence = @group.Id + 1000 })
where item.UserId == 1
orderby item.Sequence
select new { Id = @group.Id, Name = @group.Name, Calc = @group.Calc };
```

Based on [this question and accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query) I have also tried using a [DTO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236638.aspx#id0080022) like this...

```
class GroupViewSequenceDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Calc { get; set; }
}

from @group in context.GroupViews
join seq in context.GroupSequences on @group.Id equals seq.GroupId into groupSeq
from item in groupSeq.DefaultIfEmpty(new GroupSequence { Id = @group.Id, UserId = 1, Sequence = @group.Id + 1000 })
where item.UserId == 1
orderby item.Sequence
select new GroupViewSequenceDTO { Id = @group.Id, Name = @group.Name, Calc = @group.Calc };
```

But I still get the same error as before (cannot be constructed)

**The question...**

How can I write this query so that the repeater will show all 5 rows, with the first 3 in sequence order, and the last 2 added on?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the filter into the left join condition since it will be false when `item` is null.

```
from @group in context.GroupViews
from seq in context.GroupSequences.Where(x => @group.Id == x.GroupId && x.UserId == 1).DefaultIfEmpty()
orderby seq.Sequence ?? int.MaxValue
select new GroupViewSequenceDTO 
{
   Id = @group.Id, 
   Name = @group.Name, 
   Calc = @group.Calc 
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Magnus - minor typo (`item.UserId` should be `x.UserId`).  I'm getting all 5 rows through, but the two null items are at the start of the list

Comment: Then order the items `descending` instead.

Comment: But that would have the first 3 items in descending order (sorry, I'm being of a newbie with all this... I'm sure I could work it eventually, I'm just struggling to get my head into a totally different way of coding after a decade of writing data handlers by hand)

Comment: If Sequence is if type `int` you can for example set it to `int.MaxValue` when it is `null`.

Comment: Perfect, perfect, perfect... I'd managed to figure something similar out myself (`(seq.Sequence != null ? seq.Sequence : @group.Id + 1000)`), but that is exactly what I needed - thanks Magnus :-)

Comment: Or in general you could try `orderby new { ISN = seq.Sequence == null ? 1 : 0, seq.Sequence }`