# Cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query. Error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
public ActionResult CreateApp(Guid id)
    {

        SMICParkingLotApplicationEntities1 dbb = new SMICParkingLotApplicationEntities1();
        ApplicationDATA applicationData = (from a in dbb.ApplicationDATAs
            where a.ApplicationID == id
            select new ApplicationDATA
            {
                ApplicationID = a.ApplicationID,
                BrandModel = a.BrandModel,
                CrNo = a.CrNo,
                OrNo = a.OrNo,
                DatePosted = a.DatePosted,
                PoR = a.PoR,
                PlateNo = a.PlateNo,
                VehicleType = a.VehicleType

            }).FirstOrDefault();

        ApplicationSlotViewModel applicationSlotViewModel = new ApplicationSlotViewModel
        {
            ApplicationDatas = applicationData,
            Application = new Application()
        };
        return View(applicationSlotViewModel);
```

Dunno what to do it always shows this error **Cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.** Error Help Plss..

Comment: possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the type of `ApplicationDatas` in your ViewModel is `ApplicationDATA`, you can set it directly with the result of your query:

```
var applicationData =dbb.ApplicationDATAs.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.ApplicationID == id);
ApplicationSlotViewModel applicationSlotViewModel = new ApplicationSlotViewModel
{
        ApplicationDatas = applicationData,
        Application = new Application()
};
```

You can't project the result of your query using an existing entity type. Check the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query) that I quote in my comment

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Remove className after new keyword. Try below code.

```
    var applicationData = (from a in dbb.ApplicationDATAs
        where a.ApplicationID == id
        select new 
        {
            ApplicationID = a.ApplicationID,
            BrandModel = a.BrandModel,
            CrNo = a.CrNo,
            OrNo = a.OrNo,
            DatePosted = a.DatePosted,
            PoR = a.PoR,
            PlateNo = a.PlateNo,
            VehicleType = a.VehicleType

        }).FirstOrDefault();
```