# How to send LINQ query to a View without using ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I can use a ViewModel and pass my LINQ Query through it to the View with @model directive as `@model IEnumerable<MyWebProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel>`. **Question**: But, 1. What if I don't want to use a View Model in the following example: 2. What would be my @model directive in that case?

**ViewModel**:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string CustomerName{ get; set; }
    public int CustomerOrderNo{ get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyViewModel vm= new MyViewModel();
    var vm = (from c in db.Customers
             join o in db.Orders
             select new { CustomerName = c.Name, CustomerOrderNo = o.OrderNo}).ToList();
            return View(vm);
}
```

**View**:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyWebProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerOrderNo)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: you should'nt do that, use viewmodel, why you don't want to use it?

Comment: Your linq expression returns a collection of anonymous objects. You cannot bind your view to that. You should create and use a view model/DTO

Comment: Hardcoded viewmodels always good way to implement a view, if you do not have an exact irregular situation.

Comment: 1. http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-3-applications/  2. just remove the entire line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always can use `Tuple`. Like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyViewModel vm= new MyViewModel();
    var vm = (from c in db.Customers
             join o in db.Orders
             select new Tuple<string, int>(c.Name, o.OrderNo).ToList();
            return View(vm);
}
```

And on View:

```
@model IList<Tuple<string, int>>
```

You can access it like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Model.Item1
}
```

But **DON'T DO IT, PLEASE**.

Comment: You also seem to be using ViewModel shown in you Index() method above. Did you mean vm not as a YmVievModel() class instance variable - instead just a variable for the LINQ Query?

Comment: @nam that's not ViewModel actually. It's `Tuple`

Comment: I see - thanks. `MyViewModel vm= new MyViewModel();
` line is not used.

Comment: Now Tuple is the view model. What's in a name?

Comment: Are you sure about "You always can use Tuple". EF requires parameterless constructors and property setters, hence does not support projecting to `Tuple`s. See for instance [Create a Tuple in a Linq Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33545249/create-a-tuple-in-a-linq-select/33545601#33545601).