# Filter DbSet by list of objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core with SQL Server to filter a list of division entities by a list of passed in search objects. I want to return division that match the criteria in any one of the search objects. The search object class looks like:

```
public class SearchObject
{
    public int DivisionId { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the query I tried:

```
var searchObjects = new List<SearchObject> { ... };

 IQueryable<Product> query = myContext.Divisions.Where(div =>
     searchObjects.Any(searchObj =>  
            searchObj.Status == div.Status && 
            searchObj.DivisionId == div.DivisionId))
    .Select(...);
```

When the IQueryable enumerates, I get an error stating: "The Linq Expresion DbSet ... Could not be translated ..." What I need is something like .Contains(), but that works with a list of SearchObj.

Comment: do `myContext.Divisions.toList().Where(div =>
     searchObjects.Any(searchObj =>  
            searchObj.Status == div.Status && 
            searchObj.DivisionId == div.DivisionId))
    .Select(...);`

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen - this is one step in composing a larger IQueryable, and for reasons of performance, I am trying to avoid intermediate enumeration.

Comment: Check this [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71667616/10646316) witch references to function implementation,

Answer (score 1):

Well you have the right idea by

> What I need is something like .Contains(), but that works with a list of SearchObj.

and this is how you'd do it

```
var searchObjects = new List<SearchObject> { ... };
var searchIds = searchObjects.Select(x => x.Divisiond) //.ToList() perhaps?
var searchStatus = searchObjects.Select(x => x.Status) //.ToList() perhaps?
//not you can simply use .Contains and it should generate a WHERE EXISTS query

 IQueryable<Product> query = myContext.Divisions
          .Where(div =>
              searchIds.Contains(div.DivisionId) &&
              searchStatus.Contains(div.Status))
    .Select(...);
```

Comment: Not quite. I need the results to filter by DivisionId and Status in the same searchObject.

Comment: @clhereistian Can you check my edit if it works? If it doesn't just create anonymous types with new `{ Id = ..., status = ...}` and compare those

Comment: I feel hidden errors. Imagine search input of `searchObject`: `{Id = 1, Status = 10}, {Id = 2, Status = 0}` and data  `{Id = 2, Status = 10}`. Record will be successfully returned, but it do not match requirements.

Comment: Trick with tuples will not work, as I know EF Core LNQ translator.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33545249/create-a-tuple-in-a-linq-select, I searched this first. I'll post the anonymous objects code anyway

Comment: @AMunim, `Select` is different case. EF Core can relax translation requirements because it just materialising objects. In `Where` case it have to create complex search condition or make join to `VALUES` table - both solutions are unsupported.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Check the edits now

Comment: @AMunim - that first edit fails with the original error. The second edit I don't understand. The SearchPOCO, which you don't define, looks to be exactly like my SearchObj?

Comment: I know it will not work. Check by yourself before posting. You have just manipulates with constructors and `Contains`. EF Core cannot translate this.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - I don't see a solution posted by you. There is a link to another post which has a link to another post which has an extension method posted without details of how to use it.

Comment: Yes, it is, just SO admins warning me to do not duplicate this solution. So just follow links.