# EF Code First -how to filter related objects using Include extension method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, linq-to-entities

Given a EF-Code First CTP5 entity layout like:

```
public class Person 
{
     public List<Children> Childrens { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Children
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do:

```
PersonQuery.Include(x => x.Childrens.OrderByDescending(child => child.Age).Take(3))
```

and get only 3 older childrens from list.

for example:

I got Person with 5 childrens ages 5, 10, 15, 20, 25

I want select the person + list of 3 childrens ages 25, 20, 15.

this is the error I have:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties. Parameter name: path

Comment: Don't the `.OrderByDescending(child => child.Age).Take(3)` have to be placed *after* the `Include` instead of `in` it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do a query inside `Include` extension method to filter the related objects, you must specify only a navigation property or an expression to compose additional includes. Take a look this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(VS.113).aspx) (Remarks section) to see how you can use it.

You can filter related objects when you project your query using `Select` method:

```
var query=PersonQuery.Include(x => x.Children)
                     .Select(p=>new {PersonName=p.Name,
                                     Children=p.Children.OrderByDescending(child => child.Age).Take(3)});
```

If you want to know more about how to project Linq to Entities queries, then you should see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query).