# Linq join result to List

Tags: c#, linq, list, join, var

Here is a linq inner join which returns what I want

```
 var innerJoinQuery =
                from employee in DbSet
                join department in DbContext.Set<Departments>() on employee.DepartmentID equals department.ID
                select new { ID = employee.ID, FirstName = employee.FirstName, LastName = employee.LastName, DepartmentID = employee.DepartmentID, DepartmentName = department.Name };


            List<Employees> innerjoinresult_as_employees_list = innerJoinQuery.AsEnumerable().Cast<Employees>().ToList();
```

Model of Employees is:

```
public class Employees
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }   

        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    }
```

My problem is that I cannot have var innerJoinQuery as `List<Employees>` so I can return it.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, you are looking for a way to transform your result to a list of `Employees` instances.

You can do that by updating the projection part of your LINQ statement. Currently it projects to an antonymous object. you want to project to  `Employees` type

```
var innerjoinresult_as_employees_list =(from employee in DbSet
                                        join department in DbContext.Set<Departments>() 
                                        on employee.DepartmentID equals department.ID
                                        select new Employees { 
                                                   ID = employee.ID, 
                                                   FirstName =  employee.FirstName, 
                                                   LastName = employee.LastName,
                                                   DepartmentID = employee.DepartmentID, 
                                                   DepartmentName = department.Name }
                                        ).ToList();
```

The result (variable `innerjoinresult_as_employees_list`'s value will be a list of `Employees` class)

Comment: Do you have a class called `Employees` ?

Comment: I get this error ... -> The entity or complex type 'Ferrero.Model.Employees' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: my error is explained in this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query

Answer (score 1):

You are projecting to an anonymous type, not `Employee` objects.  Change your query to:

```
var innerJoinQuery =
    from employee in DbSet
    join department in DbContext.Set<Departments>()
        on employee.DepartmentID equals department.ID
    select new Employee { ID = employee.ID, 
                          FirstName = employee.FirstName, 
                          LastName = employee.LastName, 
                          DepartmentID = employee.DepartmentID, 
                          DepartmentName = department.Name 
                        };

List<Employees> innerjoinresult_as_employees_list = innerJoinQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: I get this error ... -> The entity or complex type 'Ferrero.Model.Employees' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: Is `Employee` an entity type in your model?  You can;t project to entity types - only anonymous types on non-entity (DTO) types.  Why are you trying to project to an entity type instead of using them directly?

Comment: Yea yea.. Now I know that.. Thank you for your answer you were right :)

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this, but try it out; you need to project to the correct type:

```
     var innerJoinQuery =
                (from employee in DbSet
                join department in DbContext.Set<Departments>() on employee.DepartmentID equals department.ID
                select new Employees{ ID = employee.ID, FirstName = employee.FirstName, LastName = employee.LastName, DepartmentID = employee.DepartmentID, DepartmentName = department.Name }).ToList();

List<Employees> employees = new List<Employees>(innerJoinQuery);
```