# How to filter specific columns from a child table Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have 3 tables with 1:many parent child relation

- TableA
- TableB (child of TableA)
- TableC (child of TableB)

I am able to retrieve all of the data from these tables with query

```
var data = dbContext.tableA.where(a => a.ID == rowID)
           .Include(a => a.tableB.Select(n => n.tableC)).SingleOrDefault();
```

For `TableC`, I don't want all of the columns to be retrieved from database. I just want ID, `TableC_FK` columns data to be retrieved for `TableC`.

How do I do that?

Comment: Is it ok for you to select anonymous type?

Comment: What do you mean by anonymous type here? var data? If so, no.. I just gave as an example.

Comment: I mean your `var data` will not be type of `tableA`.

Comment: "data" is type of TableA.

Comment: I know that it is type of `TableA`. I try to say that it will not be type of `TableA` if you want to do custom select. is it OK for you?

Comment: You'll have to project the results (fields) you want. You can either create a ViewModel/DTO or project the results into an anonymous type. You have to look into the .Select().

Comment: No. It should be of type TableA.

Comment: "You cannot (and should not be able to) project onto a mapped entity. You can, however, project onto an annonymous type or onto a DTO:" See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think you cannot project into `TableA` unless you have scheme that support it.
>   IMHO The best option is either anonymous project or Use Viewmodel/DTO suggested by @jpgrassi

You can use anonymous here, more tutorial of anonymous projection [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx)

```
var data = dbContext.tableA
                    .where(a => a.ID == rowID)
                    .Select(tableA=> new 
                    {
                       firstColumn = tableA.FirstColumn,
                       tableC = tableA.SelectMany(tableB=>tableB.TableC),
                    }.SingleOrDefault();
```