# Entity Framework Include Single Object from One-To-Many Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, one-to-many

I'm trying to construct a single query to fetch the list of all Tour objects, with each tour's latest version preloaded (latest being most recently created). See the models below. Each `Tour` can have multiple associated `TourVersion` objects

```
class Tour {
    public Guid TourId { get; set; }
    public virtual TourVersion CurrentTourVersion { get; set; }
    // Other properties etc.
}
class TourVersion {
    public Guid TourId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    // Other properties etc.
}
```

I'm able to accomplish what I want running another query for each `Tour`:

```
var tours = context.Tours.ToList();

foreach (var tour in tours)
{
    tour.CurrentTourVersion = context.TourVersions
        .Where(t => t.TourId == tour.Id)
        // ToUnixTime is a custom extension method that returns a long
        .OrderByDescending(t => t.CreatedOn.ToUnixTime())
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I'd like to be able to accomplish this in a single query. Any suggestions?

Comment: You already have a `CurrentTourVersion` navigation property. That means EF will load it for you (either lazily or eagerly)

Comment: Are you allowed to change your class structures? I think one-many is usually coded differently in EF code first

Comment: I don't think it will because each Tour has multiple TourVersions. How could EF know which of the multiple TourVersions to load?

Comment: Your current class structure shows that each tour has a single tourversion.

Comment: Each tour has multiple tourversions, but only ONE current Version (i.e. the latest one). The challenge here is to find the most recent version and prefetch it for each tour in a single query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving it with this:

```
var tours = (from tour in context.Tours
             join v in context.TourVersions on tour.TourId equals v.TourId
             where v.CreatedOn == context.TourVersions.Select(b => b.CreatedOn).Max()
                select new
                {
                    TourId = tour.Id,
                    CurrentTourVersion = v
                }).ToList().Select(tour => new Tour
                {
                    TourId = tour.Id,
                    CurrentTourVersion = tour.CurrentTourVersion
                });

return tours.ToList();
```

Explanation of why this works:

- Joins each tour with the most recent version

  - Finds the most recent version by selecting version against maximum date
- Creates an anonymous object with the TourId and CurrentTourVersion fields
- Maps that to a list of Tour objects

EF has a restriction to force you to put the results of a join into an anonymous object. See [this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12532338/744398)

Comment: This restriction doesn't exist. I'm sure you can do `select new Tour` at the first `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework automatically loads related entities for you until the context is alive. You get the list of Tours by

```
var tours = dbContext.Tours.ToList();
```

for example and you can get the tour version by calling

```
tours[i].CurrentTourVersion;
```

Unless dbContext is disposed somewhere before you get tour version in that case you are going to need eager loading (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)). This way you get and keep the related objects.

```
var tours = dbContext.Tours.Include(obj=>obj.CurrentTourVersion).ToList();
```