# Entity Framework throwing error when fetching a nested object using .include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a query here that fetches a single entity object and only one nested entity that meets a specific condition, but I'm receiving an error when executing it.

Here is the query

```
Profile profile = dbContext.Profiles.Where(i => i.ApplicationUserGuid == guiId)
               .Include(i => i.ProfileImages.Where(k => k.IsMainImage == true)).First();
```

And here is the exception error message

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
>   Parameter name: path

I also tried running it with another .First(), but still same error message

```
Profile profile = dbContext.Profiles.Where(i => i.ApplicationUserGuid == guiId)
              .Include(i => i.ProfileImages.Where(k => k.IsMainImage == true).First()).First();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't filter related entities inside an `Include`, you are going to need to project your query with the expected result or use [explicit loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#explicit):

```
Profile profile = dbContext.Profiles
                           .Where(i => i.ApplicationUserGuid == guiId)
                           .First();
dbContext.Entry(profile) //Explicit Loading
         .Collection(b => b.ProfileImages) 
         .Query() 
         .Where(k => k.IsMainImage == true).Take(1)
         .Load();
```

If you do the projection it will be only one round trip to your database, and if you use explicit loading it will be two.

Just a FYI, in case you think to project the result, project to an anonymous type or onto a DTO. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query).

Comment: I'm following your explicit loading example and its working but it's returning all the nested entities and not just the one that meets the where condition!

Comment: I have edited my answer, `Take` method should fix that

Comment: I'm still a little unsure why all images are being returned when all except 1 meet the where condition? Then what's the purpose of the where condition? If it's not working? And I tried Take(1) and it still returns all the images!

Comment: Oh, just one meet the condition? Are you completely sure? Did you check your db?

Comment: yes I'm sure I'm looking at the property IsMainImage now and only 1 row has that value of true

Comment: It's not a big deal because I guess I can filter later on, but it seems like something isn't correct if the where condition isn't working/filtering properly?!

Comment: that's weird my friend, `Where` method should control that

Comment: oh I know why, it's because the first call returns all images in profile! But I'm still confused, shouldn't the explicit call after filter out everything that's unwanted?

Comment: Or shouldn't the first call lazy load everything, because it's not, it's loading all nested entities!

Comment: it must be because  lazy loading is enabled  and you are accessing to that navigation property some how in your code. My advice is disable lazy loading, check the first link that I quoted

Comment: you mean I'm enabling eager loading?

Comment: Did you remove the `Include` call from your query, right?

Comment: It's enabled by default,https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: yes, I removed the include, my two queries look just like yours

Comment: ok, I fixed it! I set dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; above the queries

Comment: That was what I was suggesting to do, another thing that you can do is remove the `virtual` keyword from your navigation properties, that way your entity doesn't meet the conditions to create a proxy class that handles lazy loading and tracking changes

Comment: just to clarify, if I remove the virtual keyword, then no images will be loaded and I can remove the dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; statement?

Comment: so then I guess the question I have to ask myself, from an architectual perspective, is do I want to load all related entities when fetching a profile? Because I have other nested entities, not just images!

Comment: What I always do is disable lazy loading and use eager loading instead when I need some nav prop, but maybe your design works better with lazy loading. That property is being loaded because it has been accessed in some point in your code. Projecting your queries to ViewModel classes is a good practice, you will find good tutorials if your search a little.