# The entity or complex type 'FPSDB_newModel.Form_Attachment' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, entity, dto

I am using Entity Framework DB first approach. When I want to pull the data from DB I use the method **GetForm_AttachmentByAppID**.I get the following run time error when I call this method  from my code:

> ```
> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in     EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The entity or complex type 'FPSDB_newModel.Form_Attachment' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
> ```

[image: The photo showing the Entity Framework file]

```
public partial class Form_Attachment
{
public int Form_AttachmentID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> AttachmentCategoryID { get; set; }
public int ApplicationID { get; set; }
public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
public string DocumentName { get; set; }
public string DocumentSize { get; set; }
public Nullable<byte> RoleID { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> SelectionForExtRev { get; set; }

public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
public virtual AttachmentCategory AttachmentCategory { get; set; }
public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

The above file is auto-generated and the code is present in **FPSModel.cs** while below is my code to pull data

```
public List<Form_Attachment> GetForm_AttachmentByAppID(int applicationID)
{
    var context = new FPSDB_newEntities();
    var data = (from f in context.Form_Attachment
                where
                (
                f.ApplicationID== applicationID
                )
                select new Form_Attachment
                {
                    Form_AttachmentID = f.Form_AttachmentID,
                    AttachmentCategoryID = f.AttachmentCategoryID,
                    EmployeeID = f.EmployeeID,
                    ApplicationID = f.ApplicationID,
                    DocumentName = f.DocumentName,
                    DocumentSize = f.DocumentSize,
                    RoleID = f.RoleID,
                    Description = f.Description,
                    SelectionForExtRev = f.SelectionForExtRev
                }).ToList();
    return data;
}
```

Also here is the DB definition of my table **Form_Attachments**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Form_Attachment](
[Form_AttachmentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[AttachmentCategoryID] [int] NULL,
[ApplicationID] [int] NOT NULL,
[EmployeeID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[DocumentName] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[DocumentSize] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[RoleID] [tinyint] NULL,
[Description] [ntext] NULL,
[SelectionForExtRev] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Form_AttachmentID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Form_AttachmentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have read this [The Projection should not be on to a mapped entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query)
So if i make a class **Form_Attachments1** just like auto-generated  **Form_Attachments** so will it be a Data Transfer object DTO and is it a right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public List<Form_Attachment> GetForm_AttachmentByAppID(int applicationID)
{
    var context = new FPSDB_newEntities();
    var data = (from f in context.Form_Attachment
                where
                (
                f.ApplicationID== applicationID
                )
                select f).ToList();
    return data;
}
```

or this:

```
data = context.Form_Attachment.Where(p => p.ApplicationID == applicationID).ToList();
```

I can't test it now, but this should work. You don't need to map because 'f' means your 'Form_Attachment' entity class already. If you were using a DTO class like 'Form_AttachmentDto', then you would need to map it like this:

```
public List<Form_AttachmentDto> GetForm_AttachmentByAppID(int applicationID)
    {
        var context = new FPSDB_newEntities();
        var data = (from f in context.Form_Attachment
                    where
                    (
                    f.ApplicationID== applicationID
                    )
                    select f).Select(p=>new Form_AttachmentDto() 
                        { 
                        //...
                        // here comes the mapping code
                        //..
                        }
                    ).ToList();
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: perfect solution ! Thanks Dear

Comment: I am glad i helped.

Comment: For your other question, which i've just noticed, using DTO classes is a better approach. I always use DTO classes as a middle level (Business Layer) between Data Access Layer and Presentation Layer. This approach provides me flexibility with interfering the data like validating, logging or authorizing etc. There are a lot more benefits of course, i can't write them all here. Good codings  :)

Comment: Thanks alot again also pls if you can answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695514/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-dto