# is there a way to get rid of DTO

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dto

I am using Entity  Framework. I have the following query in which I get data using two tables **Application** and **Employee** connected by a foreign key **EmployeeID** in Application Table. The tables have 1-1 relationship . 
Is there a way to simplify the following code and get rid of the DTO Employee1 
which is the same as auto generated Employee class

```
public List<Employee1> GetApplicant(int ApplicationID)
{
    var context = new FPSDB_newEntities();       
    var data = (from a in context.Applications
                join e in context.Employees on a.EmployeeID equals e.EmployeeID
                where
                (
                   a.ApplicationID == ApplicationID
                )
                select new Employee1
                {
                    EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID,
                    SecondEmail = e.SecondEmail,
                    EmailID = e.EmailID,
                    Title = e.Title,
                    Name = e.Name,
                    Rank = e.Rank,
                    POBox = e.POBox,
                    Phone = e.Phone,
                    JoinDate = e.JoinDate,
                    Status = e.Status,
                    DepartmentID = e.DepartmentID.Value,
                    NameString = e.NameString,
                    Department = e.Department,
                    ParentDept = e.ParentDept,
                    DepartmentAr = e.DepartmentAr,
                    NameAr = e.NameAr,
                    NameStringAr = e.NameStringAr,
                    TitleAr = e.TitleAr
                }).ToList();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: If the two classes are really identical, then if you change the return type to `public List<Employee>` and alter your select statement accordingly then it should work. Assuming you can change the rest of your app to accept that different type.

Comment: no it doesnot work and gives an error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676957/the-entity-or-complex-type-fpsdb-newmodel-form-attachment-cannot-be-constructe

Comment: what I'm suggesting is pretty much the same as the accepted answer, I just didn't spell it out. So I assume that answer worked for you. The question you've just linked me to is older, so I'm confused how that's relevant or what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to return list of Employees, just select e which refers to Employee and don't use Employee1 as a DTO.

```
public List<Employee> GetApplicant(int ApplicationID)
{
    var context = new FPSDB_newEntities();       
    var data = (from a in context.Applications
                join e in context.Employees on a.EmployeeID equals e.EmployeeID
                where
                (
                   a.ApplicationID == ApplicationID
                )
                select e).ToList();
    return data;
}
```

Another way is this, which I would prefer because of readability:

```
public List<Employee> GetApplicant(int ApplicationID)
{
    var context = new FPSDB_newEntities();       
    var data = context.Applications.Where(p=>p.ApplicationID == ApplicationID).Select(p=>p.Employee).ToList();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Again a perfect Answer! :) Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. But you should do some tutorials about LINQ :)