# What prevents Entity Framework from creating classes when projecting using Select?

Tags: entity-framework

Usually when I query with Entity Framework I do something like the following:

```
using (var db = MyDataContext()){
    db.MyTable.Select(d => new DataModel(){
        Id = d.Id,
        Name = d.Name
    });
}
```

But sometimes I get an error at runtime "the entity or complex type 'DataModel' cannot be constructed in a linq to entities query". How can I know if a type  can be constructed without running the program and testing?

Comment: Does it throw the same error in the above code? As long as you are projecting into a dto class, I don't think you should any problems.

Comment: But what makes something a DTO class is my question. When is a DTO not a DTO according to Entity Framework?

Comment: You cannot project to a partial model/table class. Rest all should be ok.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query

Comment: Ah ok, so as long as the class isn't already mapped to a table, I can project into it safely? Add an answer and I'll accept it.