# Fetch single table data from Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have five table in Sql-Server, and which have linked using foreign keys.

Below i am displaying the image of database tables and links.

For example i tried to fetch user data of a particular user ID from user table, i am getting all rows with inner join to all five tables.

But i just need data from only User table. I tried to write query , sql procedure and also Linq.

In all i am getting the data which is joined with all five tables.

How can i achieve the data from only one table ?

My Try using Procedure ,

```
       object[] xparams = {
        new SqlParameter("@UserName", "Admin"),
        new SqlParameter("@UserPwd", "1234"),
        new SqlParameter("@AppType", 1)

        };
    var user = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec proc_authenticate_tocken @UserName, @UserPwd, @AppType ", xparams);
```

Another using Query ,

```
db.Users.SqlQuery("select * from users where PhoneNumber ='"+ user_name + "' and   Password = '" + password + "' and TypeId=" + user_type + " and Status = 1;").ToList();
```

Lsing Linq,

```
var ty = db.Users.Where(emp => emp.Password == password && 
        emp.PhoneNumber == phone_number)
                           ;
```

[image: Table]

Code below is Entity Model Class, auto generated using Entity Framework.

```
 public partial class User
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public User()
    {
        this.TockenPools = new HashSet<TockenPool>();
        this.TockenProcesses = new HashSet<TockenProcess>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TypeId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string ActualName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastLogin { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LoginCount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Status { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TockenPool> TockenPools { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TockenProcess> TockenProcesses { get; set; }
    public virtual User Users1 { get; set; }
    public virtual User User1 { get; set; }
    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just disable lazy loading.

Comment: Don't you need any related data from other tables?

Comment: I need data from other tables, but in this context i just need data from USER table, later i need data with Joins from other tables too.

Comment: check my answer. I wrote it according to my understanding about your Q. If anything different notify me.

Comment: I am trying to make lazyLoading disable ,  But still i am getting same error.

Comment: Well, please show how you disabled LL and what "error" you get. If you only query `db.Users`, without LL, there's no way you can get related data. *Unless* you loaded the data into the same context before querying users.

Comment: Its Not in code, in property i disabled it, but data from other tables are removed, but table names are showing in result.

Earlier I disabled in code in derived class of dBContext, 
 this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

Comment: *table names are showing in result* What do you mean? If you query `db.Users.Where(emp => emp.Password == password && emp.PhoneNumber == phone_number)` the query can't possibly contain any joins.

Answer (score 0):

Hi According to my understand about your question, you need only the data from `users` table. So please try below code,

```
var SelectedUser = db.Users.Where(emp => emp.Password == password && 
    emp.PhoneNumber == phone_number).select(usr => new User{UserName =  usr.UserName , Password = usr.Password }).FisrtOrDefault();
```

like wise you can include anything related to your `user` class

Comment: Thank you for your effort for me,  but 
I am getting following error on using your syntax,

-----
  Message "The entity or complex type 'XXXXXXXXXXXXeModel.User' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query." string

Comment: You can create a duplicate `class` which have the properties you nee from `users` class and use that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query this link will help you to understand what I'm trying to tell about the exception

Comment: can you please see my answer above , and please correct me if my approach is wrong .

Comment: It is better to have a 'class' bind to it, then it is easy when handling you result. I have done the same approach with that User class..

Comment: Is Entity Framework will give always result joining all tables , what ever is linked using Foregin_Key , though we query for only single table ?

Is that so ??

Answer (score 0):

In My Context, i managed to get the result, using LINQ itself,

```
But i am not so sure that this is a good practice or not, since the
```

> ObjUser object carries all data by joining all the tables in the digram.

```
        var Result = from ObjUser in db.Users
                           where ((ObjUser.PhoneNumber == user_name ||
                           ObjUser.UserName == user_name) &&
        (ObjUser.Password == password))
                           select new
                           {
                               ObjUser.Id,
                               ObjUser.ActualName,

                               ObjUser.LastLogin,
                               ObjUser.PhoneNumber
                           };
        var ty = db.Users.Where(emp => emp.Password == password &&
        emp.PhoneNumber == user_name)
                           ;
```

Comment: *carries all data by joining all the tables in the diagram* Well, as I said above, that's impossible. Convince me by showing the SQL query that is generated by this single LINQ statement.