# The entity or complex type 'WebApi.DbConnection.LoginCrediential' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

Why am I getting an Error whilst I'm fetching data from db?

```
 public class LoginCrediential
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
    }
```

Repo.cs

```
 public IEnumerable<LoginCrediential> GetLoginCrediential()
        {
 var x = (from n in db.LoginCrediential orderby n.Id
                    select new LoginCrediential
                    {
                        Id=n.Id,
                        UserName=n.UserName,
                        Password=n.Password,
                        Role=n.Role
                    }).ToList();
            return x;
        }
```

**WebApi.cs** Here Im trying to access my Repo.cs class

```
  [HttpGet]
            [Route("GetCredentials")]
            public IHttpActionResult GetCredentials()
            {
                var x = ObjCrenditals.GetLoginCrediential();
                return Ok(x);

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `LoginCredential` is an **entity generated by Entity Framework**

This is not the right way to make a custom selection. Please refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query).

You can use  **anonymous** type or a **DTO** (*Data Transfer Objects*) like this :

```
public class LoginDTO
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Username{ get; set; }
    public string Password{ get; set; }
    public string Role{ get; set; }

}
```

And your method will return a List of **DTO's**.

```
 public IEnumerable<LoginDTO> GetLoginCrediential()
 {
                 var x = (from n in db.LoginCrediential orderby n.Id
                    select new LoginDTO
                    {
                        Id=n.Id,
                        UserName=n.UserName,
                        Password=n.Password,
                        Role=n.Role
                    }).ToList();
            return x;
}
```

Hope this helps !