# Get Specific object after a join using LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to retrieve a specific class related to a table in Entity Framework using linq for join and where conditions as follows:

```
                var result = (from a in db.Persons
                             join b in db.Person_IDs on a.PersonId equals b.PersonId
                             where b.FaceId == faceId
                             select new
                             {
                                 PersonId = a.PersonId,
                                 Name = a.Name,
                                 Address = a.Address,
                                 Picture = a.Picture,
                                 City = a.City,
                                 Estate = a.Estate,
                                 Phone = a.Phone,
                                 CellPhone = a.CellPhone,
                                 BlackList = a.BlackList
                             }
                             ).FirstOrDefault();
```

I would like the "result" object being returned as a Person object. In the above case, I need to create a new Person object and add the fields that came from the result.

Is it possible? I tried some ways and using some samples and researches but none of all alternatives worked for me.

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

All right, after some readings, the best way I found to do this was creating a DTO class for my Person object and returning this DTO class in my funcion as follows:

```
PersonDTO result = (from a in db.Persons
                             join b in db.Person_IDs on a.PersonId equals b.PersonId
                             where b.FaceId == faceId
                             select new PersonDTO
                             {
                                 PersonId = a.PersonId,
                                 Name = a.Name,
                                 Address = a.Address,
                                 Picture = a.Picture,
                                 City = a.City,
                                 Estate = a.Estate,
                                 Phone = a.Phone,
                                 CellPhone = a.CellPhone,
                                 BlackList = a.BlackList
                             }
                             ).FirstOrDefault();

            db.Dispose();

            return result;
```

All right, it worked fine, but one thing bothers me: why create another class identical to the EF class? Why can't EF class be used this way?

I am working with one table, but a program with, for example, 20 tables will force me to have 20 entity classes and 20 entity DTO classes!

As a beginner, I think this way of work a bit disorganized or nonsensical, making the traditional way (using data readers, commands and connections). Even being more bureaucratic, it don't have de need of "duplicated" objects.

Can somebody please provide this answer?

**UPDATE 2**

As requested: as I don't wat an anonymous type returning in my function, I tried returning the entity class (Person), but when I do this I get the following error in my application execution:

**"The entity or complex type 'Models.Person' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."**

So the solution for this was create a DTO class (or a viewmodel class, whatever).

Comment: why not just `select a` instead of `select new ...` since you're not using any of the fields from `b` in your result?

Comment: you're creating an anonymous type

Comment: what you did is correct...you just need to select person instead

Comment: Do you already have a view model or **Class Person** with the property Name , address , PersonID etc ??

Answer (score 3):

If you have `Person` objects in your database, and you want `Person` objects, why are you going to the trouble of creating an anonymous type?

Why not just try

```
var result = (from a in db.Persons
              join b in db.Person_IDs on a.PersonId equals b.PersonId
              where b.FaceId == faceId
              select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It is a function that returns a Person object, but I can return an anonymous type to a Person object. I already tried this.

Comment: I don't think I understand the problem you ran into with this. Was there an error message?

Comment: The type of `result` should be `Person` with this code. Unless something is funky with your context definition.

Comment: @LucasNeves You can return an anonymous object, nice. But why would you do that if you can select and return a typed `Person` straight from your selection? You tried this, what happened? Please edit your question adding the necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do

```
var result = (from a in db.Persons 
    join b in db.Person_IDs on a.PersonId equals b.PersonId
    where b.FaceId == faceId
    select new Person
    { 
        PersonId = a.PersonId, 
        Name = a.Name, 
        Address = a.Address, 
        Picture = a.Picture, 
        City = a.City, 
        Estate = a.Estate, 
        Phone = a.Phone, 
        CellPhone = a.CellPhone, 
        BlackList = a.BlackList
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

This should work as long as the Person class is accessible, it's location is imported, and it has public getters/setters with properties matching the above.

If you're still having issues, try including your class definition for person and any errors you might be seeing.

EDIT: Based on the error you are seeing, I'm guessing you're trying to select only SOME of the properties on this entity. EF actually won't let you do that. You can either select the whole entity (by not specifying the properties and just selecting `a`) or you can create a custom DTO that you can map to like I do above.

EF doesn't like incomplete mapping because it makes the state confusing for future model modifications. [See this answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5325797/8622724) So if you're wanting to avoid loading the whole entity, go the custom DTO route.

Comment: I'm assuming here that you may be trying to select as a class that's different from your EF object type. If it's the same as defined in your context, go with oerkelens answer.

Comment: Yes, Person returning object is the same Person object generated by Database First Entity Framework method. But when I try the suggested code I get this error: "The entity or complex type 'Models.Person' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

Answer (score 1):

you code is correct !! go for this solution as it has minimum modification
**just select person**

```
 person result = (from a in db.Persons
                             join b in db.Person_IDs on a.PersonId equals 
                             b.PersonId
                             where b.FaceId == faceId
                             select new person
                             {
                                 PersonId = a.PersonId,
                                 Name = a.Name,
                                 Address = a.Address,
                                 Picture = a.Picture,
                                 City = a.City,
                                 Estate = a.Estate,
                                 Phone = a.Phone,
                                 CellPhone = a.CellPhone,
                                 BlackList = a.BlackList
                             }
                             ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Tried this but I get the following error during program execution: "The entity or complex type 'Models.Person' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query." Should I create a DTO class for this?

Comment: so dont you already have a Class Person ????  You need to create classes for every reusable entity ...that is good programming practice

Comment: Sorry, but is it a good pratice having entity classes and dto classes?

Comment: **Noooo** in entity framework...we use something called as **view models** tho they are like DTO in some aspect .. but try to create **view models** instead of **DTO**