# Left outer join using LINQ Query Syntax EF Core C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have a question in regards with the below,

1. Left outer join of two tables who are not connected through Foreign Key.
2. Order by the results matched in second table.
3. I would like this to be done in LINQ Query method syntax as I am adding lots of conditions depending on the input provided along with skip and limit.

If we have below Product and Favorite tables

[image]

[image]

So the output that I would like to have is:

[image]

meaning with the favorites as part of first set and which are not favorites should be behind them. Below are the tries that I did.
I am able to join the tables get the output but not sure how I can make sure that in the first page I get all the favs.

This answer was very near to what I thought but it gets the result and then does the ordering which will not be possible in my case as I am doing pagination and using IQueryable to get less data.

[Group Join and Orderby while maintaining previous query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456715/group-join-and-orderby-while-maintaining-previous-query)

Open to any solutions to achieve the same.

```
[Table("Product")]
public class ProductModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName {get; set;}
    public bool IsFavorite { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserFavorite")]
public class UserFavoriteModel
{
    [Required]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid Identifier { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public FavoriteType Type { get; set; }
}

// Gets products
private async Task<List<ProductModel>> GetProductsAsync(
    Guid categoryId, 
    Guid subCategoryId, 
    int from,
    int limit)
{
    var query = _context.Products.AsQueryable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryId))
        query = query.Where(product => product.CategoryId == categoryId);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subCategoryId))
        query = query.Where(product => product.SubCategoryId == subCategoryId);

    query = query.Skip(from).Take(limit);

    var products = await query.ToListAsync();

    query = query.GroupJoin(
    _context.Favorites.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(favorite => favorite.Type == FavoriteType.FASHION)
    // This user Id will come from context just adding for overall picture.
    .Where(favorite => favorite.UserId == userId),
    //This orderby if I add will not make any difference.
    //.OrderByDescending(favorite => favorite.Identifier),
    v => v.ProductId,
    f => f.Identifier,
    (product, fav) => new { product, fav }).
    SelectMany(x => x.Fav.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                    (x, y) => SetFavorite(x.Project, y));

}

private static ProductModel SetFavorite(ProductModel v, UserFavoriteModel si)
{
    v.IsFavorite = (si != null);
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
var query =
   _context.Products.AsQueryable().Select(p => new ProductModel {
      ProductId = p.ProductId,
      ProductName = p.ProductName,
      IsFavorite =
         _context.Favorites.Any(f =>
            f.Identifier = p.ProductId &&
            f.Type == FavoriteType.FASHION &&
            f.UserId == userId
         )
   }).OrderByDescending(favorite => favorite.Identifier);
```

Comment: AsNoTracking inside projection and without returning records - something new for me ;)

Comment: @Aducci Thanks alot. This looks simpler than I thought, lot to learn :). there are some typos that might be useful for others   f.Identifier = p.ProductId (this should have ==) and  order should be OrderByDescending(favorite => favorite.IsFavorite). I had one small clarification if I have large number of fields in ProductModel is there a way to simplify that rather than declaring all in select. I tried 
Select(p => {
      p.IsFavorite =favs condition here
         ; return p;}) 
but I suppose this is not supported in Expressions.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I just made this method to post in SO and forgot to add the return part :). The AsNoTracking as I understand was to use for only reads and I am using that even for _context.Products.AsNoTracking, Is there a reason I should not be using. It is because of IQueryable?

Comment: `AsNoTracking` is for "notifying" ChangeTracker to do not register loaded entities. If you did not get records, just `Count` or `Any`, etc. - so nothing for change tracking.