# How to exclude grandchildren with linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have an entity framework class (Document) with a child (Provider) that has an array of objects (Documents).  I want to pull my `Document` class and include it's `Provider` child but not include the Provider's array of `Document` objects. I can't remove the documents property from Provider because I do need the documents array at other times.  How do I pull the documents with providers, but exclude each providers documents array with linq?

Here's my class structure:

```
Document {
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
    public virtual Provider Provider { get; set; }
}
Provider {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to get my document objects using linq like this:

```
db.Documents.Where(x => x.Id == Id)
.Include(x => x.Provider)
.ToList();
```

And here's what the result looks like:

```
[{
    'DocumentName': 'document_one.pdf',
    'Provider': {
        'Name': 'Jim Smith',
        'Documents': [
            {
                'DocumentName': 'document_one.pdf'
            },
            {
                'DocumentName': 'document_two.pdf'
            },
        ]
    }
}]
```

So how do I accomplish getting this exact result set, just without the Provider.Documents array being populated?  Again, I can't remove the Documents property from the Provider class because I need it at other times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a blog post and a SO answer I combined to answer my question.  I have to create a special DTO for the documents in which the Provider property is also a special DTO for the providers.  The DTO's can exclude the properties then I have to do a select statement to convert the database classes into the DTO's like this:

```
db.Documents.Where(x => x.Id = Id)
.Include(x => x.Provider)
.Select(x => new DocumentDTO{
    DocumentName = x.DocumentName,
    Provider = new ProviderDTO{
        Name = x.Provider.Name
    }
})
.ToList();
```

Blog post [here](https://colinmackay.scot/2011/07/31/getting-just-the-columns-you-want-from-entity-framework/).
SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is only for Get's and not for saving just Iterate the documents and set them to null.

```
var documents = db.Documents.Where(x => x.Id == Id)
.Include(x => x.Provider)
.ToList()

documents.ForEach(x => x.Provider.Documents = null);
```

My guess is you don't want this because it's being exposed to the client during serialization,  If that's the case you probably should be creating A DTO