# cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DAL.model>'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I want to retrieve all determined columns from the model table as queryable 
I write code blow it shows me

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

any help to solve this error with the best practice:**

```
public IQueryable<DAL.model> GetAllmodels()
    {
        var models = (from d in db.models
                      where (d.Model_Deleted == false)
                      select (
                      new
                      {
                          d.Model_ID,
                          d.Model_Name,
                          d.Model_Image

                      })).AsQueryable();

        return models;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of selecting `anonymous` object with `new { .. }` Try as below with `new DAL.model() { ... }`.

```
public IQueryable<DAL.model> GetAllmodels()
{
    var models = (from d in db.models
                  where (d.Model_Deleted == false)
                  select (
                  new DAL.model()
                  {
                      Model_ID = d.Model_ID,
                      Model_Name = d.Model_Name,
                      Model_Image = d.Model_Image
                  })).AsQueryable();

    return models;
}
```

Comment: fine it solves the error but gives me another error  Message = "The entity or complex type 'project.model' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

Comment: Please check this question. I hope it will help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12532338/9695286