# How can I avoid NotSupportedException?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I red this article: [The entity cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query) , but guess it's not fully related to my issue.

I have this code:

```
public class Class1
{
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
        public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

[Table("Class2")]
public class Class2
{
        [Key]
        [Column("Prop1")]
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }

        [Column("Prop2")]
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }

        [Column("Prop3")]
        public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

and method edit where I want to use these ones:

```
using (var data = new Context())
{
    var config = data.Class2.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Prop1.Contains(some_string));
    if (config != null)
    {
        config.Prop1 = class1_instance.Prop1;
        config.Prop2 = class1_instance.Prop2;
        config.Prop3 = class1_instance.Prop3;
    }
    data.Entry(config).State = EntityState.Modified;
    data.SaveChanges();
}
```

So what I want to get is simplify editing, instead of assigning each property one by one I want to write something like `config = class1_instance;`

So I've inherited `Class1` from `Class2`, but getting

> `System.NotSupportedException` (the entity or complex type "Class1" cannot be constructed in a Linq to Entities query).

How can I handle it?

Comment: You have to create an `Interface` between Class1 and Class2. That way you can later convert to one or another.

Comment: Where do you get tjhe exception? What is the full exception? Your code doesn't include any inheritance or class1=class2 assignment ?

Comment: What is "blabla", also what is configModel?
Not enough to see whats going on here.

Comment: You can have a look to inheritance mapping :https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph

Comment: @Nekeniehl Hi! Thanks for ur reply! I've created the interface: public interface IConfig { string Prop1 { get; set; } string Prop2 { get; set; }  string Prop3 { get; set; }}, and both classes inherit this interface, but I still cannot write config = class1_instance; with error "cannot implicitly convert type Class2 to Class1". Or should I do something else ?

Comment: @PaulSwetz Hi! "blabla" - is just string. Concerning "configModel" - I've edited the question.

Comment: @Nekeniehl the same if I'm trying to cast "class1_instance" to Interface.

Comment: Of course, not only with the Interface is enough, now you have to create the Conversion method, implicit or explicit.

Answer (score 3):

Don't inherit the DTO class from the entity class because EF6 will treat the DTO  as an entity participating in some of the supported database inheritance strategies.

Instead, use the [SetValues(object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbpropertyvalues.setvalues?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-6.2.0#overloads) of the `DbPropertyValues` returned by the `CurrentValues` property of the `DbEntityEntry`:

> Sets the values of this dictionary by reading values out of the given object. The given object can be of any type. Any property on the object with a name that matches a property name in the dictionary and can be read will be read. Other properties will be ignored. This allows, for example, copying of properties from simple Data Transfer Objects (DTOs).

e.g.

```
Class1 source = ...;
var target = data.Class2.FirstOrDefault(...);
if (target != null)
{
    data.Entry(target).CurrentValues.SetValues(source);
    data.SaveChanges();
}
```

Note that the target entity is already attached (tracked) by the db context, so there is no need to set the entry state to `Modified`.

Comment: I've tried this one: using (var data = new Contex())
            {
                var config = data.Class2.FirstOrDefault(c => c.OperatorName.Contains(blabla));
                if (config != null)
                {
                    data.Entry(config).CurrentValues.SetValues(configModel);
                }
                data.SaveChanges();
            }                      , but got "The property 'Prop1' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified." exception.

Comment: The PK values must be the same in order this to work. So either `Class1`sshould not have `Prop1` property, or its value has to match the `Prop1` of the target entity. There  is no the EF "out of the box" solution. If you can't satisfy these requirements, then, well,  use your original approach of setting properties manually.

Comment: Another way is to add `source.Prop1 = target.Prop1;` before calling `SetValues`. This way you would set manually only 1 property and all other will be set automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Now Class1 and Class2 have equal properties. Is that intended, or is this by accident, and might it be that future versions of Class2 have properties that are not in Class1?

> In entity framework, the `DbSet<...>` represent the tables of your database. the class in the DbSet represents one row in the table. The columns of your table are the non-virtual properties of the class; the virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

Class2 represents a database table. If Class1 is supposed to be equal to Class2, then what is the reason for Class1. If this equality is only now, and in future versions they might be different, you'll have to copy the properties one-by-one.

```
void UpdateValue(string someString, Class1 value)
{
    using (var dbContext = new DbContext())
    {
        Class2 fetchedData = dbContext.Class2.Where(...).FirstOrDefault();
        if (fetchedData != null)
        {   // data exists. Update the properties
            fetchedData.Prop1 = value.Prop1,
            fetchedData.Prop2 = value.Prop2,
            fetchedData.Prop3 = value.Prop3,

            // future version of Class2 may have properties that are not updated
            // no need to set state to modified. Entity Framework will detect the changes
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

If you are absolutely certain that every `Class2` is a special type of `Class1`, now and in far future, you might consider to derive Class2 from Class1:

```
class Class2 : Class1
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // properties that are in Class2, but not in Class1
}
```

This means that every non-virtual property of Class1 is represented by a column in the tables with Classes2.

Derivation won't help you, even if you derive, you'll have to copy the properties one by one. If you'll have to do this several times consider to create a function that copies the proper values for you.