# The entity or > complex type 'ChildAccessory' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to > Entities query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I think I understand the following error but I am not sure how to fix it,

> "ClassName": "System.NotSupportedException", "Message": "The entity or
>   complex type 'ChildAccessory' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to
>   Entities query.",

Should I create a DTO and return it from repository to fix the issue or there is any better fix ?

I am trying to get child accessories but also include default accessories which are in parent table.

```
public class ChildAccessoryRepository: IChildAccessoryRepository {
 private readonly EquipmentContext _context;

 public DirectoryEquipmentRepository(EquipmentContext context) {
  _context = context;
 }

 public IEnumerable < ChildAccessory > GetChildAccessories(Guid clientReference) {
  var accessories = from a in _context.Accessory
  join ca in _context.ChildAccessory
  on new {
   AccessoryId = a.Id, ClientReference = clientReference
  }
  equals new {
   ca.AccessoryId, ca.ClientReference
  }
  into ca_join
  from ca in ca_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
  where
  ca.IsActive == true ||
   ca.IsActive == null
  //select ca;
                         select new ChildAccessory
                                   {
                                       AccessoryId = ca.AccessoryId,
                                       SomeOtherColumn = ca.SomeOtherColumn,
                                       Accessory = ca.Accessory,
                                   });

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does ChildAccessory have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: You are not allowed to map to a type that is used as a table in EF. ChildAccessory is propably a table in the context already. EF prevents you from doing this, because you could potentially get objects from the database that might be impossible to track.

You can add a .AsNoTracking() after the select, or you can map to anonymous objects, and then do a .ToList, and then after the .ToList map to ChildAccessory. I found these options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query