# How to pass AnonymousType to asp.net MVC 5 view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to pass anonymous type to view but It's get Error to find The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `` 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Test.Models.BidsDetails]'. ``

> Where my model

```
public class BidsDetails
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BidsId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int BidsPrice { get; set; }

        public virtual Bids Bids { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
```

> my Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Winner()
        {
            TestDbContext db = new TestDbContext();
            var result = db.bidsDetails
                                    .GroupBy(g => g.ProductId)
                                    .Select(s => new 
                                    {
                                        productId = s.Key,
                                        BidsPrice = s.Max(m => m.BidsPrice)
                                    }).ToList();


            return View(result);
        }
```

> My view

```
@model IEnumerable<Test.Models.BidsDetails>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Winner";
}

<h2>Winner</h2>


<table class="table">   

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bids.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.ProductName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BidsPrice)
        </td>        
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I am beginner to asp.net `MVC` .
So, How to solve this problem ?

Comment: `.Select(s => new BidsDetails   { ..etc }`

Comment: If i write ```.Select(s => new BidsDetails
                                    {
                                        productId = s.Key,
                                        BidsPrice = s.Max(m => m.BidsPrice)
                                    }) ```Error productId  How can select then productId

Comment: `BidsDetails` does not contain a `productId` field.    It is `ProductID` (with a capital P).

Comment: Thanks you For answer Robert Harvey

Comment: Here I write edit this code then this Problem is create The entity or complex type ```'Test.Models.BidsDetails'``` cannot be constructed in a``` LINQ ```to Entities query.  @Robert-Harvey

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5325861

Comment: Thanks you @RobertHarvey . if you don't mind again asked to you , how also  ```select BidsId ``` here.

Comment: The same way you select ProductID?

Comment: That's mean I write ```.Select(s => new 
                                    {
                                        productId = s.Key,BidsId=key,
                                        BidsPrice = s.Max(m => m.BidsPrice)
                                    }) ```? @RobertHarvey

Comment: Were you able to get it to work with an anonymous type?

Comment: Yes...@RobertHarvey...after all I give you so many thanks for help me.

Comment: @zahidulislam is it working now?

Comment: yes. Brother atlasted it is solve. @RohanRao

Comment: But I am also tried to select BidsId But I could not solve this. only I can solved to select productId & max Bidsprice .do you help to select BidsId also. @RohanRao

Comment: @zahidulislam, why are you trying to select BidsId? This is the ID and should only be used to update or delete a record. You must use this ID in a hidden field to avoid any issues in future.

Comment: Thanks you @RohanRao for your right ans

Comment: @zahidulislam you're welcome. Is it working fine now?