# Exclude Property From Include

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have models that look like the following:

```
public class Note
{
    public long? ID { get; set; }
    public long AuthorID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Image
{
    public long? ID { get; set; }
    public byte[] Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public byte[] FullRes { get; set; }
}
```

Which I can load with the following:

```
List<Note> a = dBContext.Notes.Where(x => x.AuthorID == myId)
        .Include(x => x.Images).ToList();
```

I would however like to avoid loading the FullRes member of Image as it is large.  Something along the lines of the following (which throws an ArgumentException - The include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type.  Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.):

```
List<Note> a = dBContext.Notes.Where(x => x.AuthorID == myId)
        .Include(x => x.Images.Select(i => new Image
        {
            ID = i.ID,
            Thumbnail = i.Thumbnail
        })).ToList();
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the only way ATM is to use `Select` on the query:

```
List<Note> a = dBContext.Notes
    .Where(x => x.AuthorID == myId)
    .Select(x => new Note
    {
        ... select all note props,
        Images = x.Images.Select(i => new Image
        {
            ID = i.ID,
            Thumbnail = i.Thumbnail
        }
        .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

**UPD**

Missed that you are using EF6. Then, I'm afraid you will need not only use `Select`, but custom DTOs/anonymous classes, for example:

```
var a = dBContext.Notes
    .Where(x => x.AuthorID == myId)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        ... select all note props,
        Images = x.Images.Select(i => new 
        {
            ID = i.ID,
            Thumbnail = i.Thumbnail
        }
        .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I tested the Select query like you suggest.  When doing so I recieve a NotSupportedException: "The entity of complex type Note cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query".

Comment: @denver yep, forgot about this limitation of EF6, then DTOs or anonymous types [should help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5325861/2501279).

Comment: When you say limitation of EF6 are you saying the above would work on something newer like EF Core?

Answer (score 1):

I did not test it. You could try something like this.

```
var notes = dBContext.Notes.Where(x => x.AuthorID == myId)
.Select(x=> new {
    x.ID,
    x.AuthorID,
    Images = x.Images.Select(i=> new {
        i.ID,
        i.Thumbnail
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();

// Rewrite
List<Note> a = notes.Select(x=> new Note{
    x.ID,
    x.AuthorID,
    Images = x.Images.Select(i=> new Image{
        i.ID,
        i.Thumbnail
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  As I commented on the similar an I tested the Select query and got a NotSupportedException: "The entity of complex type Note cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query".

Comment: @denver buddy try this. If it does not work let me know.