# linq join code doesn't work

Tags: c#, linq

I have **2** records in `tblMaterials` and **zero** record in `tblMaterialTenderGroups`
But when I fetch the data to `gridview` it shows me the **two records**, and the join doesn't work

```
    public List<tblMaterial> ShowPresentMaterialInGroup()
    {
        List<tblMaterial> q = (from i in dbconnect.tblMaterials.AsEnumerable()
                               join b in dbconnect.tblMaterialTenderGroups on i.materialId equals  b.materialId
                               where b.MaterialGroupId == _materialGroupId
                               select new tblMaterial()
                               {
                                   existAmout = i.existAmout,
                                   materialId = i.materialId,
                                   name = i.name,
                                   needAmount = i.needAmount,
                                   requestAmount = i.requestAmount,
                                   unit = i.unit,
                                   requestId = i.requestId
                               }).ToList();
        return q;
    }
```

Comment: and what is your requirement? How many records you want?

Comment: It's more likely that you have data in tblMaterialTenderGroups than LINQ join stopped working

Comment: it should show nothing because tblMaterialTenderGroups  doesn't have the records that be equal with tblMaterials on materialId

Comment: I don't really have time to test it but, as I understand your question, maybe you can add some conditions like (i.materialId != null) && (b.materialId != null)

Comment: Why are you using `.AsEnumerable()`? You're going to do a full table scan by having that there and it may be screwing up your join.

Comment: @cabbott :Because i need the result to be the datasource of gridview ,

Comment: have you tried removing `.AsEnumerable()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this

```
List<tblMaterial> q = from i in dbconnect.tblMaterials
            join b in dbconnect.tblMaterialTenderGroups on i.materialId equals  b.materialId 
            select new { existAmout = i.existAmout,
                         materialId = i.materialId,
                         name = i.name,
                         needAmount = i.needAmount,
                         requestAmount = i.requestAmount,
                         unit = i.unit,
                         requestId = i.requestId}.ToList();
```

May be using returning the two records..
I read something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311034/what-is-the-effect-of-asenumerable-on-a-linq-entity)

> Using AsEnumerable will break off the query and do the "outside part"
>   as linq-to-objects rather than Linq-to-SQL. Effectively, you're
>   running a "select * from ..." for both your tables and then doing the
>   joins, where clause filter, ordering, and projection client-side.