# Entity Framework Takes Too Much Time where Adding "WHERE Clause"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm working on Schools System, and the System have many Users(teachers And Managers).

(Tools)

1. Asp.net 5 (MVC With C#) VS 2015
2. SQL SERVER (Azure)
3. Code-First Approach

Each user Assigned to One Or More Of Classes.

(The User Should only See His Classes And Students inside of Classes)

**in the other side**

to catch Each User Classes

I've write this Method

```
public static IEnumerable<Class> GetClasses()
{
    string UserId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();

    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var Job = db.Jobs.Where(j => j.UserId == UserId).FirstOrDefault();
    if (Job.EntityLevelID == 1)
    {
        var x = db.Classes.Where(a => a.Levels.SupervisionCenter.Organization.Id == Job.EntityID) as IEnumerable<Class>;
        return x;
    }
    return null;
}
```

in The Students List Controller I just want the User to get his Students which are Only in his Classes

to get all the Students i write this Code

```
var items = db.Students.AsEnumerable().Where(o => o.Name.ToLower().Contains(search)).AsQueryable();
```

This Code will Give all the Students, it takes **around 10 Sec** to load and finish all the data (But that's is not needed Bcs, i need to Filter on ClassID Field).

when i need to filter on user Permissions based-classes

I've edit the code to be

```
    var items = db.Students.AsEnumerable().Where(o => o.Name.ToLower().Contains(search))
        .Where(s => UserDB.GetClasses().Select(c => c.Id).Contains(s.ClassID.Value))
        .AsQueryable();
```

in the Previous case, when i add the where query it takes **more than 80 Sec**

**EDIT (1)
The Organization Chart Will Be**

- Organizations
- SuperVisionCenter
- Schools
- Classes

So I don't know what is the Problem I've made it here, can you please advise me for this

Thanks And Regards.

Comment: Assuming you have Server Management Studio available, I suggest that you run SQL Profiler while you're making these queries. Should be pretty obvious why your queries are so slow.

Comment: Using `AsEnumerable()` will load the entire table from the db. And I assume that `GetClasses()` will also load complete data  from db

Comment: @TiesonT. i have run the Profiler, i show that a round 1000 statements executed .

Comment: @StephanBauer But isn't mandatory ? Bcs i have remore `AsEnumerable()` the code throw me an error

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing that is slowing you down is `AsEnumerable()`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311034/what-is-the-effect-of-asenumerable-on-a-linq-entity) the effects of using `AsEnumerable()`

Basically you are getting all students in memory then running your where clause in app memory instead of just getting selected students.

**Edit 1:**

```
o.Name.ToLower().Contains(search)
```

I dont think you need to do `ToLower()` as MSSQL is case insensitive by default. This should remove the need for `db.Students.AsEnumerable()`

**Edit 2:**

Why don't you use join ? That would be a good optimisation to begin with.

something like

```
List<Student> data = (from student in db.Students
join clss in db.Classes on student.Class equals clss
where student.Name.Contains(search)).ToList()
```

Comment: I try to remore IEnumrable() it gives me this error 
'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 GetClasses()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression'

Comment: yes. that's correct. What does GetClasses() method do ?

Comment: it retrieves the user classes, I have Included in the Thread BTW.

Comment: I cannot used it as you proposed Bcs, I need one Static Class to do this Task, Bcs this Query Will Execute it in more that one Page or Controller

Comment: wow yeah you need to get rid of GetClasses(), i think include your DB structure.. and a better approach may be suggested. What is the reason you cant use navigation props and lazy loading or eager loading... that would be way better than what GetClasses is doing

Comment: @Seabizkit can you please give me more details about that, and how i can get rid of `GetClasses()` , How i can get the user Classes to get his Students inside these classes

Comment: like i said... show the db structure... and other will be able to assist. maybe research EF navigation properties and relationships

Answer (score 0):

This solved My Problem, and it takes around 3 to 4 seconds only.

```
    int[] Classes = UserDB.GetClasses().Select(c => c.Id).ToArray();

    var items = db.Students.Where(o => o.Name.ToLower().Contains(search))
        .Where(r => Classes.Contains(r.ClassID.Value)).AsQueryable();
```