# How AsEnumerable works?

Tags: c#

`AsEnumerable` is converting something into something(generic or not).
There is picture below:

[image]

I wonder that how AsEnumerable converting string array to `string[]` but `DataTable` to `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>` ?

Comment: Are you sure that `ver` is not produced by calling [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)? Because `ear` is produced by calling [this *other* method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx).

Comment: It is because they are different extension methods - one for datatable and other for enumerable

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013846/why-use-asenumerable-rather-than-casting-to-ienumerablet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are different Extension methods.
One is [DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerabl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx)e and other is [Enumerable.AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb335435.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Because both `AsEnumerable` are different

With String array, `AsEnumerable` returns `IEnumerable<T>`.

Refer to [`Enumerable.AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx)

[DataTable.AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) is defined in DataTableExtensions. It returns [EnumerableRowCollection < DataRow >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907979.aspx)